# Storing HTML Strings in HashMap

Tags: caching, hashmap

I'm planning to use make use of caching using Java Maps. Basically it would be of HashMap type. The key will be a string identifier while the value will be a full blown HTML. I don't see the HTML exceed 20 kb. However the map may hold close to 10000 records.

Are there overheads in using Map here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A HashMap is extremely efficient in a "get" and "set" scenario, because the key used gives the location, without the need for a horrible searching algorithm. Set is also useful, because we simply hash the key and store.

The overheads come in the form of the extra memory needed by the hashmap, so store the value in the key.

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526596/memory-overhead-of-java-hashmap-compared-to-arraylist) gives a pretty detailed explanation of what you want.