# In Clojure how can I tell how much memory a ref uses in total?

Tags: clojure

I want to start determining the memory requirements of my refs and how they grow with application usage. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, this isn't really a very useful thing to do: because the data used by any single ref is likely to be shared by many other refs, knowing this information isn't particularly useful.

Also, it will be highly JVM-specific - different JVM implementations may use different amounts of memory for the same Clojure structures depending on how they choose to pack data structures and pointers. For example, I believe that HotSpot pads object sizes up to the nearest 8 bytes, but other JVMs could do something completely different. Also 32/64-bit JVMs will typically use different sizes for pointers (but not necessarily in the obvious way, as some 64-bit JVMs use compressed pointers....)

If you are *still* determined to do this, the best approach would probably be to recursively descend the data structure in the ref and add up the estimated size of each sub-element.

- You'd need to make assumptions or experimentally verify the size/overhead of each possible component type. Not easy... see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258120/what-is-the-memory-consumption-of-an-object-in-java) for some of the gory details of estimating object sizes on the JVM. If you're lucky, you might be able to find a library that does this for you.
- You would also need to keep track of all objects visited - which is a also bit tricky since you'd need to compare on object identity rather than equality, and hence you wouldn't be able to use any of the standard hashmap/set types. A hashmap of (object hashcode -> collection of objects with the same hashcode) would work.
- There will also be some fun Clojure-specific corner cases to consider... e.g. are you counting meta data on a data structure or not?

On average though, I'd still recommend paying attention to the memory consumed by your **application as a whole**, rather than specific refs.

Answer (score 5):

Someone asked about this on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/7737a5299ac8a07e) a while ago (and probably someone else before that, and...). A few people provided utilities that kinda-sorta do what you might want, but I still prefer my answer: you *can't do this* in a language with such pervasive and automatic structural sharing. How do you calculate the size of a large object that you have two pointers to, etc etc.

Comment: I didn't understand the answer. What do you mean by "two pointers"?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "pervasive and automatic structural sharing"?

Comment: I mean the same thing that @Joost means: you can create one large object, and have two symbols that both refer to it, or two entries in a vector that both point to the same large object. Even if it were trivial to implement a total-memory counter that were aware of that, it would be difficult to interpret its results meaningfully regardless of how it were designed,

Answer (score 3):

Because I can't do code in comments:

```
(let [a1 large-hash-map]
     [a2 (assoc large-hash-map :foo :bar)]
   ;; now, the two 'pointers' are a1 and a2
   ;; and the data structures they point to can share
   ;; most (but not all) of their data.
   ;; making it more or less meaningless to ask
   ;; how much memory any of the bindings holds
  )
```

Whether we're talking about refs or plain bindings doesn't matter as far as your question is concerned.

Comment: Isn't it possible to only traverse the objects if they have different identity though? Is that even possible? Maybe keep a list of already visited objects?

Comment: Yeah, it's possible. But not directly from pure clojure, AFAIK. Identity in clojure is - for various reasons - mostly kept to values. For instance, two hash-maps with the same key - value pairs will be identical by design, even if they're two separate objects with differing implementations.