# Size of object serialized

Tags: java

i want to calculate size of object p in this example and size of p serialized:

```
public class Main {

    static public void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Personne p1 = new Personne("name1", "username1", 25);
        SrzDrz sr = new SrzDrz(p1, "file1");

        // Calculate size of(sr) and p1 ???
    }
}
```

Class Personne is :

```
public class Personne implements Serializable {

    static private final long serialVersionUID = 6L;
    private String nom;
    private String prenom;
    private Integer age;

    public Personne(String nom, String prenom, Integer age) {
        this.nom = nom;
        this.prenom = prenom;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return nom + " " + prenom + " " + age + " years";
    }
}
```

Class SrzDrz is :

```
public class SrzDrz {

    SrzDrz(Personne p, String name) throws IOException {

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(name);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        try {
            oos.writeObject(p);
            oos.flush();
            System.out.println(p + " serialized");
        } finally {
            try {
                oos.close();
            } finally {
                fos.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Asking the same thing again won't help, you know... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789045/memory-occuped-after-deserialization

Comment: No it's not same, here i ask how calculate the memory of simple object ! and at the last question after serialization !!!!!!!!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the memory consumption of an object in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258120/what-is-the-memory-consumption-of-an-object-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

How about this? Just write into a ByteArrayOutputStream and see how big it gets...

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOutput);
stream.writeObject(p1);
stream.close();
System.out.println("Bytes = " + byteOutput.toByteArray().length);
```

Output

```
Bytes = 200
```

Comment: if i understand your program, i don't need to serialize in file but in byteOutput ?

Comment: Yes you can just serialize into byteOutput, unless you have other reasons for writing to disk.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help :)
just last question : if byteOutput does not wrinte to disk, whers it write ?

Comment: It only exists in memory. It's a wrapper onto an array that conforms to the same interface as FileOutputStream, the only difference is that when ObjectOutStream writes to it, it writes to a byte array instead of disk, it resizes the array as necessary to fit whatever is thrown at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `File.length()` method to get the size of the file you wrote the object to.

If you want to know the size of the object in memory, try this:

http://www.javamex.com/classmexer/

Comment: i don't use any type of File !

Comment: there no methode to compute size of memory of the object without use any jar ?

Comment: @user - You use a FileOutputStream to create a file.

Comment: @user1149157 - you are using a File (within the FileOutputStream).

Comment: @user - Only if you write your own, which would be too complicated for me to answer here.