# What is size of my Bitset?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, data-structures, bit

I want to store `System.currentTimeInMillis` in memory with minimum space possible. because I have to store millions of them in memory.

I converted it to `binaryString` which gave me `41 bits`

Here is my program

```
public class BitSetSize {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final String currentTimeToBinaryString = Long.toBinaryString(currentTimeMillis);
        System.out.println("Size in bits: " + currentTimeToBinaryString.length());

        final BitSet bitSet = BitSet.valueOf(new long[]{currentTimeMillis});
        System.out.println("Bitset length: " + bitSet.length());
        System.out.println("Bitset size: " + bitSet.size());

        System.out.println("Size of biset object(bytes): " + MemoryMeasurer.measureBytes(bitSet));
    }
}
```

But when I run it I get

```
Size in bits: 41
Bitset length: 41
Bitset size: 64
Size of biset object(bytes): 48
```

**Question**
- Why does `bitSet.length()` and `bitSet.size()` differ? I assume `length()` is correct?
- I am using [memory-measurer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9368930/379235) to learn about the size of `bitSet`, but it tell me `48 bytes`, why is it not `(41/8) byte`?

I am confused

Comment: 64 bits (presumably a `long`) is the number of bits the BitSet that are actually in use to hold your data. (It can't allocate 41 bits.)

Comment: Are the times known to be within a certain range of each other?  Could you throw away the high bytes of each `long` without losing information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all I want to advise the right tool to analyze object layout schemes in JVMs - [JOL](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/). In your case(`java -jar jol-cli/target/jol-cli.jar internals java.util.BitSet`) JOL produces the following result:

```
Running 64-bit HotSpot VM.
Using compressed references with 3-bit shift.
Objects are 8 bytes aligned.
Field sizes by type: 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8 [bytes]
Array element sizes: 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8 [bytes]

java.util.BitSet object internals:
 OFFSET  SIZE    TYPE DESCRIPTION                    VALUE
      0     4         (object header)                01 00 00 00 (00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000) (1)
      4     4         (object header)                00 00 00 00 (00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000) (0)
      8     4         (object header)                f4 df 9f e0 (11110100 11011111 10011111 11100000) (-526393356)
     12     4     int BitSet.wordsInUse              0
     16     1 boolean BitSet.sizeIsSticky            false
     17     3         (alignment/padding gap)        N/A
     20     4  long[] BitSet.words                   [0]
Instance size: 24 bytes (reported by Instrumentation API)
Space losses: 3 bytes internal + 0 bytes external = 3 bytes total
```

Your calculations were not correct because of static fields, thus an empty `BitSet` itself reserves 24 bytes. Please note that these calculations are not 100% exact because it was not taken into account size of `long[]` object. So the right results are `java -jar jol-cli/target/jol-cli.jar externals java.util.BitSet`:

```
Running 64-bit HotSpot VM.
Using compressed references with 3-bit shift.
Objects are 8 bytes aligned.
Field sizes by type: 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8 [bytes]
Array element sizes: 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8 [bytes]

java.util.BitSet@6b25f76bd object externals:
          ADDRESS       SIZE TYPE             PATH                           VALUE
        7ae321a48         24 java.util.BitSet                                (object)
        7ae321a60         24 [J               .words                         [0]
```

This means an empty `BitSet` itself uses 48 bytes including long array. Also you can get the estimated object layout in different VM modes `java -jar jol-cli/target/jol-cli.jar estimates java.util.BitSet`

Answer (score 6):

> Why does bitSet.length() and bitSet.size() differ? I assume length() is correct?

The [`BitSet.size()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#size()) is the size of the internal data structure it uses to store bit values. Since the `BitSet` internally uses a `long[]` array the size is always a multiple of 64 bits. E.g. if you set the 64th bit in a `BitSet` the `BitSet` must increase the capacity of the `long[]` array in order to store that value, because each long can "only" store 64 bits. E.g.

```
BitSet bitSet = new BitSet();
for (int i = 0; i <= 64; i++) {
  bitSet.set(i, true);
  System.out.println(bitSet.size());
}
```

`BitSet.length()` returns the actual occupied bits in the `BitSet`. So if you create a new `BitSet` it's length is 0. If you then set the 4th bit the length will be 5. The `size` will remain 64, because only one long is needed to store 5 bits.

```
BitSet bitSet = new BitSet();
System.out.println(bitSet.length()); // 0
bitSet.set(4, true);
System.out.println(bitSet.size());  // 64
System.out.println(bitSet.length()); // 5
```

> I am using memory-measurer to learn about the size of bitSet, but it tell me 48 bytes, why is it not (41/8) byte?

Because of memory padding. Also known as [data structure alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).
The `BitSet` object needs mathematical 41 bytes in memory.

- 8 bytes for the object header
- 20 bytes for the `long[]`
- 8 bytes for the `long` in the array
- 4 bytes for the `wordsInUse` `int` variable
- 1 bytes for the `sizeIsSticky` `boolean`

But the jvm can't allocate 41 bits so it rounds it to the next multiple of 8. That is 48.

This size may vary, because the object header size might vary from one JVM implementation to another. So if the object header is 16 bytes. The total will be 49 and the jvm rounds it to the next multiple of 8. In this case 56.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code can't be storage for millions of `long` (`System.currentTimeInMillis`). You can use trove TLongHashSet or you should look at [sparse bitset](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/SparseBitSet). But BitSet has int index, so you should compress long from currentTimeInMillis to int. E.g. bitSetIndex = (int)(currentTimeInMillis - initialTime). It gives you 2^32 millisec (~ 50 days) interval starting from initialTime.

```
//store sample for bitset:
bitSet.set(System.currentTimeInMillis());
```

**EDIT**

One BitSet object allocates more than 100 bytes on the heap. So you should reuse one BitSet object for a lot of long values. The simplest way is to use long value as index inside BitSet and set value as true at this index. But there are several problems (I described them above):

1. BitSet has int index not long
2. java.util.BitSet is not memory effecient.

Comment: `can't be storage for millions of long`, can you please explain why?

Answer (score 1):

See java doc of [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html).

> Every bit set has a current size, which is the number of bits of space
>   currently in use by the bit set. Note that the size is related to the
>   implementation of a bit set, so it may change with implementation. The
>   length of a bit set relates to logical length of a bit set and is
>   defined independently of implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As BetaRide mentioned, the actual size that the BitSet takes up is implementation-specific. That said, in the Oracle/OpenJDK implementations (at least, in 6, 7, and 8), the basic element of state is a [`long[]` of words](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/BitSet.java#l92). That means that the size is always a multiple of 64.

As for the 48 bytes, I count in the code:

- 16 bytes [for the BitSet object itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012302/learn-about-object-overhead-in-jvm)
- 20 bytes for the `long[]` object (16 for the object, 4 for the length)
- 8 bytes for the array's content (each element is 8 bytes, but you only have one)
- 4 bytes for `int wordsInUse`
- 1 bytes for `boolean sizeIsSticky`

Which yields 49 -- not far off the 48 you're seeing. If those [object headers are compressed](http://arturmkrtchyan.com/java-object-header), but padding is also introduced, then that's probably where the 48 is coming from.