# Is there anyway to store bits in Java without memory overhead?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, jvm, bitset

This has caught my interest and attention since yesterday. I am trying to store bits in Java and hit by Memory Overhead.

My first question regarding same is [What is size of my Bitset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251379/what-is-size-of-my-bitset)

Based on the answers I looked at other references and found [Memory Usage](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/object_memory_usage.shtml) guide.

Then I looked at `BitSet` source code which looks like

```
public class BitSet implements Cloneable, java.io.Serializable {
    /*
     * BitSets are packed into arrays of "words."  Currently a word is
     * a long, which consists of 64 bits, requiring 6 address bits.
     * The choice of word size is determined purely by performance concerns.
     */
    private final static int ADDRESS_BITS_PER_WORD = 6;
    private final static int BITS_PER_WORD = 1 << ADDRESS_BITS_PER_WORD;
    private final static int BIT_INDEX_MASK = BITS_PER_WORD - 1;

    /* Used to shift left or right for a partial word mask */
    private static final long WORD_MASK = 0xffffffffffffffffL;

    /**
     * @serialField bits long[]
     *
     * The bits in this BitSet.  The ith bit is stored in bits[i/64] at
     * bit position i % 64 (where bit position 0 refers to the least
     * significant bit and 63 refers to the most significant bit).
     */
    private static final ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields = {
        new ObjectStreamField("bits", long[].class),
    };

    /**
     * The internal field corresponding to the serialField "bits".
     */
    private long[] words;

    /**
     * The number of words in the logical size of this BitSet.
     */
    private transient int wordsInUse = 0;

    /**
     * Whether the size of "words" is user-specified.  If so, we assume
     * the user knows what he's doing and try harder to preserve it.
     */
    private transient boolean sizeIsSticky = false;

    /* use serialVersionUID from JDK 1.0.2 for interoperability */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7997698588986878753L;

    /**
     * Given a bit index, return word index containing it.
     */
    private static int wordIndex(int bitIndex) {
        return bitIndex >> ADDRESS_BITS_PER_WORD;
    }

.....
}
```

As per the calculation based on `Memory Guide`, this is what I calculated

```
8  Bytes: housekeeping space
12 Bytes: 3 ints
8  Bytes: long
12 Bytes: long[]
4  Bytes: transient int // does it count?
1  Byte : transient boolean
3  Bytes: padding
```

This sums to `45 + 3 bytes (padding to reach multiple of 8)`

This means an empty `BitSet` itself reserves `48 bytes`.

But my requirement was to store bits, What am I missing? What are my options here?

Thanks much

**UPDATE**

My requirement is that I want to store total of `64 bits` in two separate fields

```
class MyClass{
    BitSet timeStamp
    BitSet id
}
```

and I want to store millions of `MyClass` objects in memory

Comment: How many bits do you need to store? If millions, then the 48 bytes overhead is negligible vs the actual bits stored. If only a few then you could just use an int or a long or a few longs or a long[].

Comment: You forgot to specify how many bits you want to store. The cheapest way to store "bits" is inside a primitive type, e.g. int = 32 bits. What you perceive as a lot of overhead in BitSet doesn't amount to much if you need to store many bits (thousands or more).

Comment: Just update the requirement. thanks for mentioning it

Comment: Yes BitSet begins to become interesting with say 256 bits. If you can live with 64 bits, use long. And BitSet offers easy operations of course.

Comment: Do you want to pack all the MyClasses together or keep them like this?

Comment: @harold, can you please explain? My idea is that I should be able to `sort/order` them as well based on `timsStamp`, so I will put them in a `Collection`

Comment: `static`-fields aren't instance-bound. This means they don't take away any space in the object at all.

Comment: I don't know why you're counting the static fields as overhead.

Comment: Why model *simple* data as bits? Your requirement looks like its best served by modeling the data as primitive fields, e.g. two simple int's.

Comment: @Durandal, I want to save `System.currentTimeInMillis` which gives `long`. Is it safe to case this `long` into `int`?

Comment: Note that Java 10 might get support for primitives as generic type parameters and "value types". Then it might be possible to actually implement Set<int> as a type that doesn't need so much overhead. It could be a value type and just use 64 bits like a "long". Those would be exactly the kind of language features you need.

Comment: Oh, so you meant *two times 64 bits*? I took your edit as "64 bits total". But my suggestion still stands. Model them as primitives, just use long where needed.

Comment: @daydreamer like put them all in a packed array, with no object wrappers. You could still sort them, but it would be trickier, so probably not a great fit in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This sums to 45 + 3 bytes (padding to reach multiple of 8) This means
>   an empty BitSet itself reserves 48 bytes.

First of all I want to advise the right tool to analyze object layout schemes in JVMs - [JOL](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/). In your case(`java -jar jol-cli/target/jol-cli.jar internals java.util.BitSet`) JOL produces the following result:

```
Running 64-bit HotSpot VM.
Using compressed references with 3-bit shift.
Objects are 8 bytes aligned.
Field sizes by type: 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8 [bytes]
Array element sizes: 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8 [bytes]

java.util.BitSet object internals:
 OFFSET  SIZE    TYPE DESCRIPTION                    VALUE
      0     4         (object header)                01 00 00 00 (00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000) (1)
      4     4         (object header)                00 00 00 00 (00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000) (0)
      8     4         (object header)                f4 df 9f e0 (11110100 11011111 10011111 11100000) (-526393356)
     12     4     int BitSet.wordsInUse              0
     16     1 boolean BitSet.sizeIsSticky            false
     17     3         (alignment/padding gap)        N/A
     20     4  long[] BitSet.words                   [0]
Instance size: 24 bytes (reported by Instrumentation API)
Space losses: 3 bytes internal + 0 bytes external = 3 bytes total
```

Your calculations were not correct because of static fields, thus an empty `BitSet` itself reserves 24 bytes. Please note that these calculations are not 100% exact because it was not taken into account size of `long[]` object. So the right results are `java -jar jol-cli/target/jol-cli.jar externals java.util.BitSet`:

```
Running 64-bit HotSpot VM.
Using compressed references with 3-bit shift.
Objects are 8 bytes aligned.
Field sizes by type: 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8 [bytes]
Array element sizes: 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8 [bytes]

java.util.BitSet@6b25f76bd object externals:
          ADDRESS       SIZE TYPE             PATH                           VALUE
        7ae321a48         24 java.util.BitSet                                (object)
        7ae321a60         24 [J               .words                         [0]
```

This means an empty BitSet itself uses 48 bytes including long array. 
In order to optimize memory footprint you can write your own implementation of `BitSet`. For example in your use case following options are available:

```
public class MyOwnBitSet {
    long word1;
    long word2;
}

public class MyOwnBitSet2 {
    long[] word = new long[2];
}

public class MyOwnBitSet3 {
    int index;
}
```

JOL produces the following result:

```
MyOwnBitSet@443b7951d object externals:
          ADDRESS       SIZE TYPE                                                   PATH                           VALUE
        76ea4c7f8         32 MyOwnBitSet                                (object)


MyOwnBitSet2@69663380d object externals:
          ADDRESS       SIZE TYPE                                                    PATH                           VALUE
        76ea53800         16 MyOwnBitSet2                                (object)
        76ea53810         32 [J                                                      .word                          [0, 0]


MyOwnBitSet3@5a2e4553d object externals:
          ADDRESS       SIZE TYPE                                                    PATH                           VALUE
        76ea5c070         16 MyOwnBitSet3                                (object)
```

Let me explain the last example `MyOwnBitSet3`. In order to decrease memory footprint you can preallocate a huge array of `long`/`int` objects and store only pointer on the right cell. With a sufficiently large number of objects, this option is the most advantageous.

Comment: great insight @Ivan, Thanks a lot. `MemOwnBitSet3` does not suit my requirements because I need to generate `ID (timestamp, uniqueId)` continuously, thile `timestamp` is something I can get from `System.nanoTime`, `uniqueId` will be for uniquely identifying the machine.

Answer (score 4):

> My requirement is that I want to store total of 64 bits in two
>   separate fields

So just use long (64 bit integer). And just use that as a bit field. I once needed something like that, but 32 bit was enough for me, so wrote a little library class to use an int as a bit set:
https://github.com/claudemartin/smallset

Feel free to fork it and just replace int by long, 32 by 64, 1 by 1L etc.

Answer (score 0):

To store a total of 64-bits in an object you can do

```
class MyClass{
    int timeStamp
    int id
}
```

or if you don't want to overhead of an object you can do

```
long timeStampAndId;
```

The problem is how to encapsulate your operations. For a primitive.  Java doesn't help much but what you can do is

```
enum TimeStampAndId {
    /* no instances */ ;
    public static boolean isTimeStampSet(long timeStampAndId, int n) { ... }
    public static boolean isIdSet(long timeStampAndId, int n) { ... }
```

i.e. use a utility class to support the primitive type.

In the future Java will support Value Types which won't have an object overhead.