# Why is Java's String memory usage said to be high?

Tags: java, string, memory

On this [blog post](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/string_memory_usage.shtml), it's said that the minimum memory usage of a String is:

`8 * (int) ((((no chars) * 2) + 45) / 8)` bytes.

So for the String "Apple Computers", the minimum memory usage would be 72 bytes.
Even if I have 10,000 String objects of twice that length, the memory usage would be less than 2Mb, which isn't much at all. So does that mean I'm underestimating the amount of Strings present in an enterprise application, or is that formula wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

String storage in Java depends on how the string was obtained.  The backing `char` array can be shared between multiple instances.  If that isn't the case, you have the usual object overhead plus storage for one pointer and three `int`s which usually comes out to 16 bytes overhead.  Then the backing array requires 2 bytes per `char` since `char`s are UTF-16 code units.

For `"Apple Computers"` where the backing array is not shared, the minimum cost is going to be

1. backing array for 16 chars -- 32B which aligns nicely on a word boundary.
2. pointer to array - 4 or 8B depending on the platform
3. three `int`s for the offset, length, and memoized hashcode - 12B
4. 2 x object overhead - depends on the VM, but [8B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/258150/20394) is a good rule of thumb.
5. one `int` for the array length.

So roughly 72B of which the actual payload constitutes 44.4%.  The payload constitutes more for longer strings.

---

In Java7, some JDK implementations are [doing away with backing array sharing](http://java-performance.info/changes-to-string-java-1-7-0_06/) to avoid pinning large `char`[]s in memory.  That allows them to do away with 2 of the three `int`s.

That changes the calculation to 64B for a string of length 16 of which the actual payload constitutes 50%.

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible to save character data using less memory than a Java String? Yes.

Does it matter for "enterprise" applications (or even Android or J2ME applications, which have to get by on a lot less memory)? Almost never.

Premature optimization is the root...

Answer (score 1):

Compared to a other data types that you have, it is definitely high. The other primitives use 32 bits,64 bits,etc.

And given that `String` is immutable, every time you perform any operation on it, you end up creating a new `String` object, consuming even more memory.

Comment: Because String is immutable, the operations you perform on it can actually *save* space, because the Strings can share memory.

Comment: But every time you create a new `String` object, wouldn't it occupy more memory?

Comment: Primitives use 32 bytes?  I think you meant bits. :)

Comment: @Makoto oops. Silly Silly mistake. Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: "Apple Computers".substring(3) will not occupy a lot of extra memory (just the overhead for the object instance).

Comment: @Thilo compared that to any other primitive, a little extra memory is still a little extra, isn't it?

Comment: why are you comparing a 16 character sequence to a primitive? The most compact way you could store it in is a 16 byte array.

Comment: but even that memory consumption is still memory consumption, isn't it? I might be wrong, still on the learning curve. :-)

Comment: @Kazekage occupying more memory when creating new String depends on the way it [creates](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/lexical.html#3.10.5). In case of constant expression actual string values are shared in global pool among references you have. Otherwise new String object always creates. You can force sharing and reusing string object by calling intern() method of String class.