# Storing more than 85000 strings in ArrayList

Tags: java, xml, jvm

I don't think this question is asked before, there is some clues(google search) that ArrayList can hold any size of data if JVM allows it to. The thing is I need to store some url links in arraylist and while program runs need to store more urls(strings) if it is not already in arrayList.

I thought storing strings in XML file, but it is not idle. Because each time I add new string I have to check whether it already exists.

I like to know if there is any other way to tackle this problem.

Comment: Would a database be too old school? Then maybe something like memcached would be an alternative...

Comment: I thought about it, but the thing is I am building desktop application. I may be able to use sqlite3. But not sure about it.

Comment: Implementation questions are off-topic here.  Try asking your question over at Stack Overflow, but please improve it by adding more detail about what you're trying to accomplish.  It's unclear from your question what the actual problem is.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So you think that I should use ArrayList. I can't ask this question in stackoverflow because I don't have any working example.

Comment: Your question says that you need to store 85000 items.  It also says ArrayList can hold this many items.  So what is your problem?  Stack Overflow doesn't require code, but it does help if you have some.

Comment: I think his main problem would be that he wants to check for duplicates, so maybe something indexed like a dictionary class or hash table would be better for that. I don't know enough of the Java environment, but I guess there exists something on that line.

Comment: Why do you want an ArrayList instead of a data-structure designed for sets? Such as a hashtable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Set will automatically overwrite duplicate keys. Here is an [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131081/why-is-javas-string-memory-usage-said-to-be-high) on memory use of Java strings. Even if the URLs are fairly long it should fit in 10MB or less. You should be allocating way more heap than that to your JVM by default so it won't be a problem.

Comment: Yes, a Set seems to be the definitive solution. Just add the urls on the Set, an HashSet for instance. Java Strings have an efficient hash so you can expect a very fast insertion.

Answer (score 2):

if you don't care about order a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) is a better option which has a fast `contains()`.