# Memory size of classes and inner classes

Tags: java

I am doing an online course at the moment and the lecturer says that in Java the memory overhead of a class is 32 bytes, but an inner class is only 16 bytes. Why is this?

Comment: Ask your lecturer? What the memory overhead of an object is, depends on the JVM implementation. What you say is not true in general for any arbitrary JVM implementation.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the following thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258120/what-is-the-memory-consumption-of-an-object-in-java and what does overhead mean in this instance? Because it does depend on the JVM being used. An Object takes 8 bytes.

Comment: @Jesper It's online. Robert Sedgewick.

Comment: Since once it has been compiled an inner class ist just a specially nanmed class (outer$inner) I very mouch doubt that this is true.

Comment: @perdian that's what I thought

Answer (score 2):

The details are JVM-specific. However, the numbers given look implausible: An inner class requires a reference to the enclosing instance of the outer class, thereby requiring *higher* overhead than a top-level class.