# Hash Map Memory Overhead

Tags: java, memory, hashmap

I was studying about internal structure of Hash Map where i came across following details:

- Implementation is an array of HashMap$Entry objects:
- Each HashMap$Entry contains: 
     – int KeyHash 
     – Object next
     – Object key
     – Object Value
- Default capacity is 16 entries
- Empty size is 128 bytes
- Overhead is 48 bytes for HashMap, plus (16 + (entries * 4bytes)) for 
  array – Plus overhead of HashMap$Entry objects
- Additional 32bytes per key ↔ value entry Overhead of HashMap is
  therefore: – 48 bytes, plus 36 bytes per entry

Can anyone please explain me **"Overhead is 48 bytes for HashMap, plus (16 + (entries * 4bytes)) for 
   array"**    and **"Additional 32bytes per key ↔ value entry Overhead of HashMap is

   therefore: – 48 bytes, plus 36 bytes per entry"**     ???

I can't understand how these conclusions came i.e. how we came across this final memory details about hash map.

Answer (score 4):

[You might want to read this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258120/what-is-the-memory-consumption-of-an-object-in-java) The object overhead will vary between different CPU architectures, VM implementations and between different Java versions (e.g. OOPS, there are also suggestions of [fixnums](https://blogs.oracle.com/jrose/entry/fixnums_in_the_vm) etc.).

[But let's](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/AbstractMap.java) [see for ourselves](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/HashMap.java) for OpenJDK 7, the `HashMap` class:

---

> **Overhead is 48 bytes for `HashMap`**

Housekeeping info. *Presumably 8 bytes.*

There are three fields in the implementation that hold the views made by `keySet()`, `values()` and `entrySet()` methods. Three pointers, that's *12 bytes* on a 32-bit machine.

```
// from AbstractMap
transient volatile Set<K>        keySet = null;
transient volatile Collection<V> values = null;

// from HashMap
private transient Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet = null
```

There are three `int` fields: `size`, `threshold` and `modCount`. *12 bytes.*

There is one `float` field: `loadFactor`. *4 bytes.*

The table pointer itself (`Entry[] table`). *4 bytes.*

(the `static final` fields don't count, they are compile-time constants)

All that gives us *40 bytes* flat cost of a `HashMap` instance. It's not 48 bytes and I don't know why. Maybe I missed something, maybe your text referred to other version. These things sometimes change a little. There may have been an extra field in the past. Maybe it's padded from 40 to 48 bytes (but it shouldn't).

---

> **16 + (entries * 4 bytes) for array**

The `Entry[] table` table is instantiated when the `HashMap` is constructed, we need to count it, too.

An instantiated array takes *8 bytes* of housekeeping data, `4 bytes` for the `length` property. That's *12 bytes*, not 16. Again, no idea where that comes from.

Every entry is a pointer to an `Entry` object, so that's *4 bytes* per entry. That was easy.

---

> **Additional 32 bytes per key ↔ value entry**

Again, *8 bytes* of housekeeping.

Now, the fields:

```
final K key;    // a reference, 4 bytes
V value;        // a reference, 4 bytes
Entry<K,V> next;  // a reference, 4 bytes
final int hash; // an integer primitive, 4 bytes
```

*16 bytes.*

That's a final count of *24 bytes* per entry. Again, that's not 36.

---

I have no idea where the numbers you got there come from. Could that be an IBM vm? Could that be a 64-bit OS? Maybe the the housekeeping info is 16 bytes nowadays (will Java 8 change anything?).

Anyway, I tried to compute the memory consumption to my best knowledge.

Comment: If anyone spots a mistake in my calculations, please feel free to edit my post right away.