# Size of Java object

Tags: jvm, java

How is it possible that minimal size of Java object is 8 bytes (only the object header),

[What is the memory consumption of an object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258120/what-is-the-memory-consumption-of-an-object-in-java)

if in the C++ class representing the java object,

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/9b0ca45cd756/src/share/vm/oops/oop.hpp

i can see that the class has more members

```cpp
class oopDesc {
  friend class VMStructs;
 private:
  volatile markOop  _mark; // this is the object header
  union _metadata {
    wideKlassOop    _klass;
    narrowOop       _compressed_klass;
  } _metadata; // what about size of this member?
```

Comment: Why do you think C++ represention has more members? There are just two: _mark and _metadata, each of them is 4 bytes on 32-bit architecture. _metadata is a union, that is, _klass and _compressed_klass share the same space.

Comment: apangin: yes you are right, my fault, the one member i deleted was static member, markOop has size of 4 bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible because in 32bit JVM object contains 4 bytes of mark header and 4 bytes of class reference. Mark headers contains different information depending the object type (sizes in bits):

normal objects -> unused:25 hash:31 cms_free:1 age:4 biased_lock:1 lock:2

biased objects -> JavaThread*:54 epoch:2 cms_free:1 age:4 biased_lock:1 lock:2

Answer (score 0):

Because the header data is binary encoded. When accessing this information via JVMTI or a native call, this binary data is exploded into data types with a wider ranger.

Furthermore, these sizes are an implementation detail and vary dependant on the bitness of the VM and on the fact of the VM using so-called [compressed oops](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops). You can read out the actual header of an instance using the [JOL tool](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/) that is distributed in the OpenJDK. Also, you can find [documentation of encoding of the header](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/hotspot/file/8389681cd7b1/src/share/vm/oops/markOop.hpp) in the sourc code.