# Why 12 bytes of header is required in 64-bit JVM as compared to 8 bytes in 32-bit JVM?

Tags: java, jvm

Recently I read 30-50% of more heap is required on 64-bit beacuse of the memory layout in 64-bit archicture.

This Includes

1.the Object Header which are 12 bytes on 64-bit JVM which adds some overheads as compared to the 8 bytes on headers on 32-bit

2. Object references can be either 4 bytes or 8 bytes on 64-bit While on 32-bit it is 4 bytes

My Question is why we need 12 bytes of header in 64-bit JVM what difference does it makes ? and so is for the Object Reference too WHY ?

Comment: Because pointers of a 64bit process are twice as large (8byte) as those of an 32bit system (4byte)?

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357186/what-is-in-java-object-header and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29143399/size-of-java-object