# Java memory allocation for instance variables

Tags: java, memory, reference, int

How much space in memory in bytes does reference data types in java consume? Basically how many bytes do variables of class type take up, similar to int data type consuming 4 bytes.

Comment: Why do you think reference would allocate space and not object itself?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258120/what-is-the-memory-consumption-of-an-object-in-java

Comment: Yeah as the link says, generally accepted answer is 8 bytes.  I think it might be more on 64 bit run times though if you're using 64 bit pointers in the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

A reference variable is a pointer, and has the size of a pointer, so it depends on the JVM (32-bit or 64-bit), and whether pointers are compressed ([compressedOop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#compressedOop)).

This is the space of the *reference*, not the Object potentially referenced by the variable (when not null).