# Wrapper class RAM

Tags: java, wrapper

One thing my professor failed to explain was whether or not wrapper classes (such as `Integer.*` or `Double.*`) took up more RAM space because they have the format of an object reference and not a primitive data type.

Comment: Yes, boxed types take up more space than unboxed primitives . I'm pretty sure this is always true.

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/258150/2310289

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, boxed typed take more space because
  - of the pointer referencing it (often 64-bit on modern, non-embedded architectures)
  - of the extra fields in the native implementation of the Object (such as, possibly, reference to the class, id, etc.)

However, under the hood, at least in theory, JVM/Hotspot may be able to optimize some boxed types based on their utilization.