# does Java allocate memory for objects without instance variables?

Tags: jvm

Please help with the following question.
Assume that I have class that contains only methods. Will space in heap be allocated for objects created of this class? If yes then what does it contain?

Comment: Please see the answers here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258120/what-is-the-memory-consumption-of-an-object-in-java

Answer (score 1):

The [question linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258120/what-is-the-memory-consumption-of-an-object-in-java) by Fairoz contains most relevant data, but I'll try to narrow information to your case.

Yes. The JVM will take a contiguous space off the heap to store these objects.

The contents are specific to the JVM implementation.  In HotSpot, you can see the specifics in the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/4d9931ebf861/src/share/vm/oops/oop.hpp#l59).

- There will be a machine word called "Mark", which is defined [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/oops/markOop.hpp#l35), and is used to keep the hashCode, locking state, and garbage collection.  This takes 8 bytes.
- Next will be a pointer to the [Klass](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/4d9931ebf861/src/share/vm/oops/klass.hpp), which contains information about the class, such as methods.

If you're in a 64 bit JVM, with compressedOops enabled (as is default on java 8) the Klass pointer will take only 4 bytes.  Since you have no fields, the total size is 12 bytes. However, the JVM forces to align to a full word, so your object will use 4 bytes for padding. In total, 16 bytes.

Some useful documentation:
- https://www.infoq.com/articles/Introduction-to-HotSpot
- https://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/know-thy-java-object-memory-layout.html