# How to check the memory used per cell when reading Java Excel

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to know how much memory is used per cell when I read Excel in Java, so I want to take a picture with the console, is there any code that I can use? Or tell me another way to know.
This is the poi I use.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
```

Server memory needs to be determined.

Could not find checking memory usage when reading per cell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the memory consumption of an object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258120/what-is-the-memory-consumption-of-an-object-in-java)

Comment: Also consider a suitable [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) tool, e.g. `jconsole`.