# Arithmetic with byte in Java

Tags: java, binary

I know that the `byte` and the `short` data types are not given `2's complement` treatment in Java. What I mean by this statement of mine is demonstrated in the example below:

```
byte b1 = 0xFF;    //error, 255 is outside the range of byte
byte b2 = 0b1100;    //12 is stored, and not -4
```

Now, take the following example:

```
byte b3 = 0;
b3 += 0xFF;
System.out.println(b3);    //prints -1 on the console
```

Should the 2nd line in the above example have thrown an error, single `0xFF` is `255` and is outside the `byte` range?

Also, what this unfair game with `byte` and `short`? I mean, why not interpret them using the `2's complement system`, just like `int` and `long`?

Comment: *are not given 2's complement* ha? and you know that? ever heard of overflowing?

Comment: Why would `b2` be -4? How many bits do you think a byte is?

Comment: Oh, oh, I got it wrong. It reads it as 0000_1100, doesn't it? Hence, it stores 12. Damn, how naive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to work this out by attempting to draw logical inferences, you should read the Java Language Specification:

Point 1.  `byte` and `short` are signed types.

> "The values of the integral types are integers in the following ranges:
>
> - For `byte`, from -128 to 127, inclusive
> - For `short`, from -32768 to 32767, inclusive"   Source [JLS 4.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1)

Point 2.  The signed integral types are 2's complement.

> "The integral types are `byte`, `short`, `int`, and `long`, whose values are 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit signed two's-complement integers, respectively, and `char`, whose values are 16-bit unsigned integers representing UTF-16 code units (§3.1)."  Source [JLS 4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2)

Point 3.  You can't assign an `int` variable to a `byte` variable.

> If the type of the right-hand operand is not assignment compatible with the type of the variable ([§5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)), then a compile-time error occurs.  Source [JLS 15.26.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1)

Point 4.  You can assign an `int` compile-time constant expression to a `byte` variable *provided* that the value of the expression is in the range of `byte`.

> "In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int`:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the variable is of type `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable."  Source [JLS 5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)

Point 5.  `b3 += 0xFF` is equivalent to `b3 = (byte)(b3 + 0xFF)`

Source [JLS 15.26.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)

Point 6.  There are no `byte` or `short` literals.

Source [JLS 3.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)

Comment: Actually, I just read that there are no byte and short literals in Java (the JVM doesn't know about byte and short). That's what the problem was.

Comment: Incorrect.  The JVM does know about `byte` and `short`.  It is more complicated than you think.

Comment: Oh, is it so? I got that from https://stackoverflow.com/a/317861/6714426. Further, is there something somewhere I could read regarding this?

Comment: Reference [JVM spec 2.3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se10/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.3.1).  The complication is that there are no opcodes for doing arithmetic, bitwise or comparison on `byte` / `short` / `char`.   But there ARE opcodes that convert to and from those types.  For example, `i2b`, `baload`.

Comment: I have commented on https://stackoverflow.com/a/317861/6714426.  It is not accurate.

Answer (score 4):

They are 2's complement - no idea where you got that from (but it's wrong). This:

```
byte b1 = 0xFF;
```

does not work because it is indeed outside the range of a `byte`. This however:

```
byte b3 = 0;
b3 += 0xFF;
```

because `+=` is done on a wider range of `int`, you assign it to `byte`, which takes the last 8 bits, which happen to be `-1`.

Comment: May be I articulated it wrong. What is mean is that supposing int i = 0xFFFFFFFF. Shouldn't this throw an error as well, as it is outside the range on int?

Comment: Yes, they can. But 32 ones = -1 in 2's complement, right? Hence, it does not throw an error. Why then interpret 8 ones (in case of byte) as 255 and not -1?

Comment: @PrashantPandey because `0xFF` is a *constant* and there are no `byte` constants, for the compiler that *is* and `int`

Comment: Oh, this is what the problem was. Thank you so much for your time, and excuse my naive questions.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to convert -minus values java 8 comes with utility methods to support unsigned operations

```
byte b1 = (byte) 0xFF;
Byte.toUnsignedInt(b1); // this method will return 255
```