# Why is Java's boolean primitive size not defined?

Tags: java, boolean

The [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html#22909) says that there is limited support for boolean **primitive** types.

> There are no Java virtual machine instructions solely dedicated to operations on boolean values. Instead, expressions in the Java programming language that operate on boolean values are compiled to use values of the Java virtual machine int data type.

The above implies (although I may have misinterpreted it) that the int data type is used when operating on booleans, but this is a 32 bit memory construct. Given that a boolean only represents 1 bit of information:

- Why is a byte, or short, type not used as the proxy for a boolean instead of int?
- For any given JVM what's the most reliable way of finding out exactly how much memory is used to store a boolean type?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Short answer: yes, boolean values are manipulated as 32-bit entities, but arrays of booleans use 1 byte per element.

Longer answer: the JVM uses a 32-bit stack cell, used to hold local variables, method arguments, and expression values. Primitives that are smaller than 1 cell are padded out, primitives larger than 32 bits (long and double) take 2 cells. This technique minimizes the number of opcodes, but does have some peculiar side-effects (such as the need to mask bytes).

Primitives stored in arrays may use less than 32 bits, and there are different opcodes to load and store primitive values from an array. Boolean and byte values both use the `baload` and `bastore` opcodes, which implies that boolean arrays take 1 byte per element.

As far as in-memory object layout goes, this is covered under the "private implementation" [rules](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html#28439), it can be 1 bit, 1 byte, or as another poster noted, aligned to a 64-bit double-word boundary. Most likely, it takes the basic word size of the underlying hardware (32 or 64 bits).

---

As far as minimizing the amount of space that booleans use: it really isn't an issue for most applications. Stack frames (holding local variables and method arguments) aren't very large, and in the big scheme a discrete boolean in an object isn't that large either. If you have lots of objects with lots of booleans, then you can use bit-fields that are managed via your getters and setters. However, you'll pay a penalty in CPU time that is probably bigger than the penalty in memory.

Comment: For boolean/byte class members, is it also true, that they are also 4 bytes? The class instance is allocated as a whole on the stack, so I can imagine, JVM should probably use 1 byte per boolean/byte member and finally make an 4-byte alignment for the complete class instance. Is it so? (if you have references that prove this, please, share)

Comment: @dma_k: as noted in my response, the layout of a class instance is implementation dependent. However, note that class instances are not stored in the stack, they're stored on the heap (although you'll see some references to JDK 7 "escape analysis" moving objects from stack to heap, this appears not to be the case; see java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/…)

Comment: Sometimes packing booleans may be actually faster. Whenever the cache size matters, it may be better to pack things. For example, a segmented prime sieve works in chunks of 32 kB (L1 cache size) is way faster than a non-segmented sieve. There's some overhead between the chunks and with packing you pay the overhead eight times less often. I haven't measured it yet.

Comment: Where did you find the information that boolean can take just 1 *bit*?

Comment: @ChristophSchreiber - I'm not sure what your question is. A Boolean can have one of two values, and a bit can have one of two values. It's therefore _possible_ to represent a Boolean using one bit. I _did not_ say that any JVM implementation actually does that, and I note that the opcodes used to access primitive Boolean values in arrays are the same ones that access bytes. Or at least they were in 2008.

Comment: @kdgregory now it‘s clear

Comment: The instructions used for accessing `boolean[]` and `byte[]` are still the same in 2023. But this doesn’t imply that boolean arrays have to use one byte per element. Using the same instruction does not mean the instruction has to do the same thing. Just like there is only one `getfield` instruction for reading a field regardless of its type. It’s always known whether a `baload`/`bastore` instruction refers to a `boolean[]` or `byte[]` array. But since the specification forbids word tearing, the implementation has to choose a native element type supporting atomic read and write access.

Answer (score 9):

A single boolean somewhere in the inheritance hierarchy can use up to 8 bytes! This is due to padding. More details can be found in [How much memory is used by my Java object?](http://kohlerm.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-much-memory-is-used-by-my-java.html):

> Coming back to the question of how
>   much a boolean consumes, yes it does
>   consume at least one byte, but due to
>   alignment rules it may consume much
>   more. IMHO it is more interesting to
>   know that a boolean[] will consume one
>   byte per entry and not one bit,plus
>   some overhead due to alignment and for
>   the size field of the array. There are
>   graph algorithms where large fields of
>   bits are useful, and you need to be
>   aware that, if you use a boolean[] you
>   need almost exactly 8 times more
>   memory than really needed (1 byte
>   versus 1 bit).

Comment: How would use a boolean[] anyway?

Comment: boolean[] could be used for a mask.  Sometimes a BitSet can be better though, because it has some useful methods.

Answer (score 6):

The 5th Edition of *Java in a Nutshell* (O'Reilly) says a boolean primitive type is 1 byte.  That could be wrong, based on what the examination of the heap is showing.  I wonder if most JVMs have issues with allocating less than a byte for variables.

Answer (score 3):

CPUs operate on a specific datatype length. In case of 32bit CPUs they are 32 bits long and therefore what you call 'int' in Java. Everything below or above that must be filled or splitted to this length before the CPU can process it. This doesn't take much time, but if you need 2 CPU cycles instead of 1 for basic operations, this means doubled costs/time.

This spec is dedicated for 32bit CPUs so that they can process booleans with their native datatype.

You can only have one here: speed or memory - SUN decided for speed.

Answer (score 2):

The boolean mapping was done with a 32bit CPU in mind. The int value has 32 bits so it can be processed in one operation.

Here's a solution from [Peter Norvig's Java IAQ:
Infrequently Answered Questions](http://norvig.com/java-iaq.html#sizeof) to measure the size (with some imprecision):

```
static Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
...
long start, end;
Object obj;
runtime.gc();
start = runtime.freememory();
obj = new Object(); // Or whatever you want to look at
end =  runtime.freememory();
System.out.println("That took " + (start-end) + " bytes.");
```

Comment: Since this conversation is about primitives, you'd have to be creative in testing this since primitives aren't stored in the heap unless they're a field on an instance or an array.  And neither of those answer the question of how Java will choose to store it in the stack anyway.

Answer (score 1):

We can't tell the exact size of boolean datatype. **It's virtual machine dependent or varies from one operating system to other.**

Answer (score -11):

Why not make one .java file like this:

Empty.java

```
class Empty{
}
```

and one class like this:

NotEmpty.java

```
class NotEmpty{
   boolean b;
}
```

Compile them both and compare the .class files with a hex editor.

Comment: this is another metric altogether, unrelated to sizing the primitive boolean type in memory.