# Why does Boolean not throw a StackOverflowException?

Tags: c#

I found Boolean source code on http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/boolean.cs:

```
public struct Boolean
{
    ...
    private bool m_value;
    ...
}
```

why does it not throw a StackOverflowException?

Comment: You should explain why you think it would.

Comment: @Takendarkk bool include a bool include a a bool include a a bool include a a bool include a a bool include a a bool ........ omg

Comment: No, a Boolean include a bool.

Comment: @Takendarkk `bool` is just an alias for `Boolean`.

Comment: @juharr Then please explain how it doesn't do what the OP suggested it would.

Comment: @Takendarkk does bool and Boolean not the same thing?

Comment: @Takendarkk If I knew I'd give an answer.  I'm just saying that it isn't as simple as `Boolean` and `bool` are not the same thing.  I'm looking forward to an answer.

Comment: Probably because the compiler knows about bool/Boolean. Note the if you try something similar in your code with your own struct you'll get a compilation error `Struct member 'Tester.m_value' of type 'Tester' causes a cycle in the struct layout` as opposed to a run-time StackOverflow exception.

Comment: I understand your question, you dont mean System.Boolean is a type which CLR recognizes. & bool is a C# Primitive that C# compiler understands.     you mean the classic chicken or the egg dilemma

Comment: Removing all `System` references and `using`s makes the compiler don't know `Boolean`, but it still knows `bool`. And when you go to its definition, it takes you to... the `Boolean` struct. :)

Comment: Exactly the same happens with `Int32`, it contains a `internal int m_value;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why this works is because the bool and System.Boolean types are actually different.

The primitive bool type is a built-in type that stores 1 byte.

The System.Boolean type serves as an object wrapper for the primitive type and implements the IComparable and IConvertable interfaces. This wrapper is implemented to closely represent the primitive type so they may become logically interchangeable.

As .NET Framework users that build on the Common Type System, we simply speak of them as being the same because, in our case, the C# compiler treats the "bool" keyword as an alias for the System.Boolean type that you see implemented in mscorlib.dll.

Comment: when I use bool type in my code, which one is actually I use?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're using the System.Boolean type when you don't specify the /nostdlib compiler option, referencing mscorlib.dll normally.

Comment: I wonder where "Go To Definition" on that `bool` would take you ... In any code it takes you to the `Boolean` definition, just like `int` takes you to `Int32`.

Comment: That would be an intellisense thing in your IDE. I guess .NET Framework developers could get by without that feature ;)

Comment: Did you actually mean "1 byte" and not "bit"? Although a boolean is obviously a bit, perhaps it needs to be stored in a full byte anyway.

Comment: No, I meant 1 whole byte.

Comment: @Andrew a boolean is not a bit. It's always one (or more) byte(s) and sometimes gets optimized to 4 bytes, considering 32 bit integers are processed faster than 8 bit integers.

Comment: I know this sounds confusing. You should check out this answer to help make sense of what @Bauss is saying. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2308052/2707705