# Java object which takes the least memory

Tags: java, performance, memory, collections

This is a silly question, but here it goes.

I have a multithreaded program and a "global" Collection of unique elements. I rejected synchronized Set implementations due to performance, for the ConcurrentHashMap. I don't really need the Value part of Map, so I wanted to use the smallest Object in java in terms of memory usage. I solved this issue in a different way (single Boolean object referenced multiple times in the Map), but I am still curious what is the smallest object in Java. I always thought it to be Boolean, but that is not true I think ([Java - boolean primitive type - size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907318/java-boolean-primitive-type-size), [Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html))

Comment: Primitive types are different from objects. Boolean is immutable wrapper object, boolean is primitive type.

Comment: If you really wanted a `Set<K>`, you can use `Collections.setFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<K, Boolean>())`. This does your work for you :-)

Comment: If you really wanted the smallest Object, though, I'd probably just use `Object`... since it's the base-class of every other `Object`... :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't really matter, actually, since the value part of each association is fixed to be a reference. You might even use `null` as value here, but any other (fixed) object reference should be fine (and more convenient sometimes). I'd prefer `Boolean.TRUE` (or a similar "well known" singleton). You can then test for membership via

```
if (myMap.get(someKey) != null) { ... }
```

in addition to

```
if (myMap.containsKey(someKey)) { ... }
```

Comment: Ok, but then you can't really check if key exists (unless -> KeySet.iterator). Thus the need for a value to be able to perform this check. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @alien01 `Map.keySet().contains()`

Comment: @alien See edit. In particular, `containsKey` is always available on maps.

Comment: @Dirk using `myMap.get(someKey)` where there is no associated value  (i.e. `get` returns `null`) will cause a `NullPointerException` when trying to auto-unbox.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a `Set<K>` that is backed by a `ConcurrentHashMap`, you should use [`Collections.newSetFromMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap%28java.util.Map%29), e.g.

```
final Set<K> set = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<K, Boolean>());
```

---

Now, if you really want to reinvent the wheel, and care *that* much about memory usage, I suggest you merely use a plain `Object` as your value. Since every object in Java inherits from `Object` (the universal base class), **the size of any object in memory must be greater than or equal to the size of a plain `Object`**. You cannot use a primitives since generic type arguments must be `Object`s.

EDIT: Actually, allocating a particular object to use as your value here will take more memory than using a preexisting object which will likely be allocated for anyways. You can just use a reference to an object that will more or less *always* be allocated during VM initialization, e.g. `Object.class`. I **really** suggest you just use the first solution, though.

Answer (score 2):

An object's size consists of:

- the size of the instance variables it holds
- an 8 or 16 bytes header (depending on the Hotspot VM (32/64bit))
- a padding: its size is always padded to be a multiple of 8 bytes.

E.g (assuming a 32bit JVM) :

```
public MyBoolObject {
  boolean flag;
}
```

will take up `16 bytes`: `8bytes`(header) + `1byte`(instance variable) + `7bytes`(padding).
Since you are not interested in the map values you can set them to null. This consumes `4` or `8` bytes memory from the stack (32/64bit).

You might also check this good list on cost/elements of well-known Java data structures:
http://code.google.com/p/memory-measurer/wiki/ElementCostInDataStructures

Answer (score 0):

The primitive data types are not objects.

Since all objects in java must inherit from the super class Object. Then the smallest conceivable object in java would be a class that you define that has no members. Such a class would be pretty useless.

Answer (score 0):

The `Object` class is instantiable and its instances are definitely the smallest objects in Java. However, many other objects have exactly the same footprint, `Integer` and `Boolean` being examples on 64-bit VMs. This is due to heap memory alignment.