# Find duplicate element in array in time O(n)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have been asked this question in a job interview and I have been wondering about the right answer.

> You have an array of numbers from 0 to n-1, one of the numbers is removed, and replaced with a number already in the array which makes a duplicate of that number. How can we detect this duplicate in time *O(n)*?

For example, an array of `4,1,2,3` would become `4,1,2,2`.

The easy solution of time *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* is to use a nested loop to look for the duplicate of each element.

Comment: it doesn't have to be sorted

Comment: Forgot that one element is replaced... It ends up with [the replaced number] xor [the repeated number] with my method...

Comment: Lol, all the solutions have more or less the same approach...

Comment: Is there a community where we can discuss such questions?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

We have the original array `int A[N];` Create a second array `bool B[N]` too, of type `bool=false`. Iterate the first array and set `B[A[i]]=true` if was false, else bing!

Comment: OK, I see, but it works as my identical solution only for integral values of numbers.

Comment: @parsifal yes, you are right, i know this but forgot in the moment i write.

Comment: I agree if numbers are integers. But, what if numbers in A[] aren't integers? I think that the hash table works well in this general case.

Comment: @bitfox even if A[] are integers, the algorithm doesn' work if any integer in A[] is greater than N.

Comment: @qchen as stated in the original question: "you have an array of numbers from 0 to N-1". The max value that you can find inside the A array is N. So, you can't incur into and array index error when you use a[A[i]].

Comment: This algorithm works even if array is shuffled. As far as I understood it is sorted.

Comment: Lets say, I get the array b = [true, true, true, undefined, true, true], but then to see which value is undefined you will have to loop through it(b) again, is there a way to avoid the second looping. how can i get to know the no. of the element that  is false without looping through b.

Comment: In the following case, Do check the length of B = length of A // (the last element is repeated)

 A = [0,1,2,3,3]    
As in this case B will be

 B = [true, true, true, true]
and there will not be any undefined/false.

Comment: The simplest solution doesn't even use an extra space. Refer to @Evgeny's answer below using multiple XOR's to find the solution in O(n) time

Comment: That takes O(n) space.

Answer (score 156):

This can be done in `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space.

(The algorithm only works because the numbers are consecutive integers in a known range):

In a single pass through the vector, compute the sum of all the numbers, and the sum of the squares of all the numbers.

Subtract the sum of all the numbers from `N(N-1)/2`. Call this `A`.

Subtract the sum of the squares from `N(N-1)(2N-1)/6`. Divide this by `A`. Call the result `B`.

The number which was removed is `(B + A)/2` and the number it was replaced with is `(B - A)/2`.

### Example:

The vector is `[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]`:

- N = 6
- Sum of the vector is 0 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 5 = 12. N(N-1)/2 is 15. A = 3.
- Sum of the squares is 0 + 1 + 1 + 4 + 9 + 25 = 40. N(N-1)(2N-1)/6 is 55. B = (55 - 40)/A = 5.
- The number which was removed is (5 + 3) / 2 = 4.
- The number it was replaced by is (5 - 3) / 2 = 1.

### Why it works:

- The sum of the original vector `[0, ..., N-1]` is `N(N-1)/2`. Suppose the value `a` was removed and replaced by `b`. Now the sum of the modified vector will be `N(N-1)/2 + b - a`. If we subtract the sum of the modified vector from `N(N-1)/2` we get `a - b`. So `A = a - b`.
- Similarly, the sum of the squares of the original vector is `N(N-1)(2N-1)/6`. The sum of the squares of the modified vector is `N(N-1)(2N-1)/6 + b2 - a2`. Subtracting the sum of the squares of the modified vector from the original sum gives `a2 - b2`, which is the same as `(a+b)(a-b)`. So if we divide it by `a - b` (i.e., `A`), we get `B = a + b`.
- Now `B + A = a + b + a - b = 2a` and `B - A = a + b - (a - b) = 2b`.

Comment: Brilliant! In your assumption, N = 1 + highest key in the array. If N = highest key, then the equations are N(N+1)/2 and N(N+1)(2N+1)/6.

Comment: If the numbers are consecutive integers, just check the number before and after. If the one you're looking at is out of order, you have your answer. If it's in order but equal to its predecessor of successor, you have your duplicate. Why the need for all the fancy math?

Comment: @imray: the assumption is that the array isnt sorted.

Comment: @rici Ok, that would have been clearer if you had scrambled the array in your example

Comment: Why isn't the memory O(n)? The memory required to store the sum of the numbers grows as n grows...

Comment: @mowwwalker Assuming no integer overflow, we need only use one int to store the sum and one int to store the sum of square.

Comment: @rici I posted an alternative solution with factorial. It hadn't been posted so far and it was my first idea when I attempted a similar problem. Your solution is better in practice though.

Comment: @GilVegliach: "We have two equations in two unknowns from which X and R can be derived algebraically" is a very ["a solution exists"](http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~riesbeck/mathphyseng.html) kind of assertion :). *How* does one do the algebraic derivation, exactly? Is there a closed form?

Comment: @rici: mathematician spotted :) I added an example to make it clearer.

Comment: @mowwwalker `Why isn't the memory O(n)` (it is, and it is in O(n*), too.) Constant additional memory is enough: In the conventional RAM machine, integer size can be chosen any fixed multiple of the size needed to represent *n*. The sum of squares grows with the third power of *n*: 3 times the size for *n* should suffice.

Answer (score 32):

You can do it in O(N) time without any extra space. Here is how the algorithm works :

Iterate through array in the following manner :

1. For each element encountered, set its corresponding index value to negative. 
   Eg : if you find a[0] = 2. Got to a[2] and negate the value.

   By doing this you flag it to be encountered. Since you know you cannot have negative numbers, you also know that you are the one who negated it.
2. Check if index corresponding to the value is already flagged negative, if yes you get the duplicated element. Eg : if a[0]=2 , go to a[2] and check if it is negative.

Lets say you have following array :

```
int a[]  = {2,1,2,3,4};
```

After first element your array will be :

```
int a[] = {2,1,-2,3,4};
```

After second element your array will be :

```
int a[] = {2,-1,-2,3,4};
```

When you reach third element you go to a[2] and see its already negative. You get the duplicate.

Comment: I don't think so that logic will works if we get two 0's in an array.
For instance, array is {0,1,2,3,4,5} in which 3 is replace with 0.

Comment: What if one of the elements was 10,000 instead of 4? It would be out of bound for the array.

Comment: Above solution will work even for 0, you have to keep track of 0 in addition to setting elements one by one negative. Algorithm time will be O(n) and space O(1). Solution may not work if array is unsigned int.

Comment: @apadana This answer is only valid when `input array is 0 -> n - 1 where integers between 0 and n`

Comment: Still it is unclear if the space is O(1) as you borrow O(N) space from the array.

Answer (score 11):

Scan the array 3 times:

1. **XOR together all the array elements** -> `A`. XOR together all the numbers from 0 to N-1 -> `B`. Now `A XOR B = X XOR D`, where X is the removed element, and D is the duplicate element.
2. Choose any non-zero bit in `A XOR B`. **XOR together all the array elements where this bit is set** -> `A1`. XOR together all the numbers from 0 to N-1 where this bit is set -> `B1`. Now either `A1 XOR B1 = X` or `A1 XOR B1 = D`.
3. Scan the array once more and **try to find** `A1 XOR B1`. If it is found, this is the duplicate element. If not, the duplicate element is `A XOR B XOR A1 XOR B1`.

Comment: Scanning the array 3 times requires O(3n) time, not O(n) as mentioned by OP.

Comment: @prashant O(3n) is the same thing as O(n) - coefficients are ignored in big O notation.

Answer (score 7):

Use a `HashSet` to hold all numbers already seen. It operates in (amortized) `O(1)` time, so the total is `O(N)`.

Comment: Thats not true, inserting in HashSet is not O(1), if number rang e is much higher than size of hashTable

Comment: @AlexWien - did you see where I said "amortized"? A rehash is not dependent on the number of elements in the array, so is still considered `O(1)`. Plus, you can pre-size the set so that you don't have a rehash at all. Of course, if you have `Long.MAX_VALUE` items, you will end up with `O(N)` semantics on add/retrieve due to physical constraints on the table, but most people don't consider that (just like they don't consider that Quicksort has `O(N^2)` behavior in the worst case).

Comment: Or, to quote [Cormen *et al*](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0262033844) (emphasis added): "Under  *reasonable* assumptions, the average time to search for an element in a hash tbale is O(1)."

Comment: in this case the number range is relatively small so it won't be much higher than table size. A rehash is not expected.

Comment: Who told that the numebr range is small? In that case dont think and use the array variant (bool array int[]) If N is big the hashset will run out of memory much earlier than the array will

Answer (score 7):

I suggest using a BitSet. We know N is small enough for array indexing, so the BitSet will be of reasonable size.

For each element of the array, check the bit corresponding to its value. If it is already set, that is the duplicate. If not, set the bit.

Comment: @qPCR4vir no not the same it uses only 1/8 of the memory of your solution (with boolean)

Answer (score 4):

@rici is right about the time and space usage: "This can be done in O(n) time and O(1) space."

However, the question can be expanded to broader requirement: it's not necessary that there is only one duplicate number, and numbers might not be consecutive.

OJ puts it this way [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-the-duplicate-number/):
(note 3 apparently can be narrowed)

> Given an array nums containing n + 1 integers where each integer is between 1 and n (inclusive), prove that at least one duplicate number must exist. Assume that there is only one duplicate number, find the duplicate one.
>
> Note:
>
> - You must not modify the array (assume the array is read only).
> - You must use only constant, O(1) extra space.
> - Your runtime complexity should be less than O(n2).
> - There is only one duplicate number in the array, but it could be repeated more than once.

The question is *very* well explained and answered [here](http://keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=find-duplicate) by Keith Schwarz, using [Floyd's cycle-finding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare) algorithm:

> The main trick we need to use to solve this problem is to notice that because we have an array of n elements ranging from 0 to n - 2, we can think of the array as defining a function f from the set {0, 1, ..., n - 1} onto itself. This function is defined by f(i) = A[i].  Given this setup, a duplicated value corresponds to a pair of indices i != j such that f(i) = f(j).  Our challenge, therefore, is to find this pair (i, j).  Once we have it, we can easily find the duplicated value by just picking f(i) = A[i].
>
> But how are we to find this repeated value?  It turns out that this is a well-studied problem in computer science called cycle detection.  The general form of the problem is as follows.  We are given a function f.  Define the sequence x_i as

```
    x_0     = k       (for some k)
    x_1     = f(x_0)
    x_2     = f(f(x_0))
    ...
    x_{n+1} = f(x_n)
```

> Assuming that f maps from a domain into itself, this function will have one of three forms.  First, if the domain is infinite, then the sequence could be infinitely long and nonrepeating.  For example, the function f(n) = n + 1 on the integers has this property - no number is ever duplicated.  Second, the sequence could be a closed loop, which means that there is some i so that x_0 = x_i.  In this case, the sequence cycles through some fixed set of values indefinitely.  Finally, the sequence could be "rho-shaped."  In this case, the sequence looks something like this:

```
 x_0 -> x_1 -> ... x_k -> x_{k+1} ... -> x_{k+j}
                    ^                       |
                    |                       |
                    +-----------------------+
```

> That is, the sequence begins with a chain of elements that enters a cycle,  then cycles around indefinitely.  We'll denote the first element of the cycle that is reached in the sequence the "entry" of the cycle.

An python implementation can also be found [here](http://bookshadow.com/weblog/2015/09/28/leetcode-find-duplicate-number/):

```
def findDuplicate(self, nums):
    # The "tortoise and hare" step.  We start at the end of the array and try
    # to find an intersection point in the cycle.
    slow = 0
    fast = 0

    # Keep advancing 'slow' by one step and 'fast' by two steps until they
    # meet inside the loop.
    while True:
        slow = nums[slow]
        fast = nums[nums[fast]]

        if slow == fast:
            break

    # Start up another pointer from the end of the array and march it forward
    # until it hits the pointer inside the array.
    finder = 0
    while True:
        slow   = nums[slow]
        finder = nums[finder]

        # If the two hit, the intersection index is the duplicate element.
        if slow == finder:
            return slow
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't actually work 100%, specifically it's broken if `nums[0] = 0`  To fix it you must first locate the first index that doesn't loop on itself.

Answer (score 3):

Use hashtable. Including an element in a hashtable is O(1).

Comment: The average is O(1), given good bucket distribution. We don't need to deal with table expansions, because the maximum needed size is known at HashSet construction time. However, I suspect the problem is to achieve O(N) worst case, not O(N) average.

Comment: Using the integers as their own hashes in a hashtable means the hashes will never collide. But a hashtable is basically just a complicated bit array in this problem.

Answer (score 2):

One working solution:

asume number are integers

create an array of [0 .. N]

```
int[] counter = new int[N];
```

Then iterate read and increment the counter:

```
 if (counter[val] >0) {
   // duplicate
 } else {
   counter[val]++;
 }
```

Comment: OK. You have +1 from me. From the Q we need TIME O(N), and nothing about memory. The boolean can be 1 byte http://stackoverflow.com/a/383597/1458030. And the BitSet() need some additional trick (directly or indirectly) to set the proper bit..

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in **O(n)** time and **O(1)** space.
**Without modifying the input array**

1. The idea is similar to finding the starting node of a loop in a linked list.
2. Maintain two pointers: fast and slow

```java
slow = a[0]
fast = a[a[0]]
```

3. loop till slow != fast
4. Once we find the loop (slow == fast)
5. Reset slow back to zero

```java
slow = 0
```

6. find the starting node

```java
while(slow != fast){
    slow = a[slow];
    fast = a[fast];
}
```

7. slow is your duplicate number.

Here's a Java implementation:

```java
class Solution {
    public int findDuplicate(int[] nums) {
        if(nums.length <= 1) return -1;
        int slow = nums[0], fast = nums[nums[0]]; //slow = head.next, fast = head.next.next
        while(slow != fast){            //check for loop
            slow = nums[slow];
            fast = nums[nums[fast]];
        }
        if(slow != fast) return -1;
        slow = 0; //reset one pointer
        while(slow != fast){ //find starting point of loop
            slow = nums[slow];
            fast = nums[fast];
        }
        return slow;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the `if(slow != fast) return -1;` is redundant. It will never be true and the loop will just run infinitely.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative solution in `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space. It is similar to [rici's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14946745/913286). I find it a bit easier to understand but, in practice, it will overflow faster.

Let `X` be the missing number and `R` be the repeated number.

1. We can assume the numbers are from `[1..n]`, i.e. zero does not appear. In fact, while looping through the array, we can test if zero was found and return immediately if not.
2. Now consider:

   ```
   sum(A) = n (n + 1) / 2 - X + R

   product(A) = n! R / X
   ```

where `product(A)` is the product of all element in `A` skipping the zero. We have two equations in two unknowns from which `X` and `R` can be derived algebraically.

**Edit**: by popular demand, here is a worked-out example:

Let's set:

```
S = sum(A) - n (n + 1) / 2
P = n! / product(A)
```

Then our equations become:

```
R - X = S
X = R P
```

which can be solved to:

```
R = S / (1 - P)
X = P R = P S / (1 - P)
```

Example:

```
A = [0 1 2 2 4]

n = A.length - 1 = 4
S = (1 + 2 + 2 + 4) - 4 * 5 / 2 = -1
P = 4! / (1 * 2 * 2 * 4) = 3 / 2

R = -1 / (1 - 3/2) = -1 / -1/2 = 2
X = 3/2 * 2 = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could proceed as follows:

1. sort your array by using a Linear-time sorting algorithm (e.g. Counting sort) - O(N)
2. scan the sorted array and stop as soon as two consecutive elements are equal - O(N)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FindDuplicate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // assume the array is sorted, otherwise first we have to sort it.
        // time efficiency is o(n)
        int elementData[] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 8 };
        int count = 1;
        int element1;
        int element2;

        for (int i = 0; i < elementData.length - 1; i++) {
            element1 = elementData[i];
            element2 = elementData[count];
            count++;
            if (element1 == element2) {
                System.out.println(element2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void duplicateNumberInArray {
    int a[] = new int[10];
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){  
        System.out.println("enter no. ");
        a[i] = inp.nextInt();
    }
    Set<Integer> st = new HashSet<Integer>();
    Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){          
        if(!st.add(a[i])){
            s.add(a[i]);
        }
    }

    Iterator<Integer> itr = s.iterator();
                System.out.println("Duplicate numbers are");
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(itr.next());
    }
}
```

First of all creating an array of integer using Scanner class. Then iterating a loop through the numbers and checking if the number can be added to set (Numbers can be added to set only when that particular number should not be in set already, means set does not allow duplicate no. to add and return a boolean vale FALSE on adding duplicate value).If no. cannot be added means it is duplicate so add that duplicate number into another set, so that we can print later. Please note onething that we are adding the duplicate number into a set because it might be possible that duplicate number might be repeated several times, hence add it only once.At last we are printing set using Iterator.

Answer (score 0):

//This is similar to the HashSet approach but uses only one data structure:

```
    int[] a = { 1, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6, 5, 22, 33, 44, 11, 5 };

    LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    for (int i : a) {
        map.put(i, map.containsKey(i) ? (map.get(i)) + 1 : 1);
    }

    Set<Entry<Integer, Integer>> es = map.entrySet();
    Iterator<Entry<Integer, Integer>> it = es.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Entry<Integer, Integer> e = it.next();
        if (e.getValue() > 1) {
            System.out.println("Dupe " + e.getKey());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do using hashMap efficiently:

```
Integer[] a = {1,2,3,4,0,1,5,2,1,1,1,};
HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
for(int x : a)
{
    if (map.containsKey(x))  map.put(x,map.get(x)+1);
    else map.put(x,1);
}

Integer [] keys = map.keySet().toArray(new Integer[map.size()]);
for(int x : keys)
{
    if(map.get(x)!=1)
    {
        System.out.println(x+" repeats : "+map.get(x));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This program is based on c# and if you want to do this program using another programming language you have to firstly change an array in accending order and compare the first element to the second element.If it is equal then repeated number found.Program is

```
int[] array=new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,4};
Array.Sort(array);
for(int a=0;a<array.Length-1;a++)
{
  if(array[a]==array[a+1]
  {
     Console.WriteLine("This {0} element is repeated",array[a]);
   }
}
Console.WriteLine("Not repeated number in array");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. sort the array O(n ln n)
2. using the sliding window trick to traverse the array O(n)

   Space is O(1)

   ```
   Arrays.sort(input);
   for(int i = 0, j = 1; j < input.length ; j++, i++){
       if( input[i] == input[j]){
           System.out.println(input[i]);
           while(j < input.length && input[i] == input[j]) j++;
           i = j - 1;
       }
   }
   ```

Test case int[] { 1, 2, 3, 7, 7, 8, 3, 5, 7, 1, 2, 7 }

output 1, 2, 3, 7

Comment: `n log n` not `n ln n`. `ln` is natural logarithm (logarithm base e) whereas `log` in CS literature is logarithm base 2 unless base is specified.

Answer (score 0):

Traverse through the array and check the sign of `array[abs(array[i])]`, if positive make it as negative and if it is negative then print it, as follows:

```
import static java.lang.Math.abs;

public class FindRepeatedNumber {

    private static void findRepeatedNumber(int arr[]) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[abs(arr[i])] > 0)
                arr[abs(arr[i])] = -arr[abs(arr[i])];
            else {
                System.out.print(abs(arr[i]) + ",");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = { 4, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 1 };
        findRepeatedNumber(arr);
    }
}
```

**Reference:** http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-duplicates-in-on-time-and-constant-extra-space/

Comment: The above solution works only for non-negative integers, ```int arr[] = { 4, 2, 4, 5, -2, 3, 1 };``` will fail and print 4,4,2 which is wrong where it should just print 4.

Comment: ```int numRay[] = {0, 800, 300, 2, 7, 800, 2, 300, 1};``` when i try this also not working.

Answer (score 0):

As described,

> You have an array of numbers from 0 to n-1, one of the numbers is
>   removed, and replaced with a number already in the array which makes a
>   duplicate of that number.

I'm assuming elements in the array are sorted except the duplicate entry. If this is the scenario , we can achieve the goal easily as below :

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    //int arr[] = { 0, 1, 2, 2, 3 };
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6 };
    int len = arr.length;
    int iMax = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        iMax = Math.max(iMax, arr[i]);
        if (arr[i] < iMax) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
            break;
        }else if(arr[i+1] <= iMax) {
            System.out.println(arr[i+1]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

- O(n) time and O(1) space ;please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution with hashmap in O(n) time.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[]={1,3,2,7,5,1,8,3,6,10};
    map<int,int> mp;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

        if(mp.find(a[i]) == mp.end())
            mp.insert({a[i],1});
        else
            mp[a[i]]++;
    }

    for(auto i=mp.begin();i!=mp.end();++i){
        if(i->second > 1)
            cout<<i->first<<" ";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] a = {5, 6, 8, 9, 3, 4, 2, 9 };
int[] b = {5, 6, 8, 9, 3, 6, 1, 9 };

 for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
  {
     if (a[i] != b[i])
      {
       Console.Write("Original Array manipulated at position {0}  + "\t\n"  
                             + "and the element is {1} replaced by {2} ", i, 
                             a[i],b[i] + "\t\n" );
       break;               
      }      
  }
   Console.Read();

   ///use break if want to check only one manipulation in original array.
   ///If want to check more then one manipulation in original array, remove break
```

Comment: Please explain how you assume there are two arrays `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

This video [If Programming Was An Anime](https://youtu.be/pKO9UjSeLew) is too fun not to share.  It is the same problem and the video has the answers:

1. Sorting
2. Creating a hashmap/dictionary.
3. Creating an array. (Though this is partially skipped over.)
4. Using the Tortoise and Hare Algorithm.

Note: This problem is more of a trivia problem than it is real world.  Any solution beyond a hashmap is premature optimization, except in rare limited ram situations, like embedded programming.

Furthermore, when is the last time you've seen in the real world an array where all of the variables within the array fit within the size of the array?  Eg, if the data in the array is bytes (0-255) when do you have an array 256 elements or larger without nulls or inf within it, and you need to find a duplicate number?  This scenario is so rare you will probably never get to use this trick in your entire career.

Because it is a trivia problem and is not real world the question,  I'd be cautious accepting an offer from a company that asks trivia questions like this, because people will pass the interview by sheer luck instead of skill.  This implies the devs there are not guaranteed to be skilled, which unless you're okay teaching your seniors skills, you might have a bad time.

Answer (score -2):

```
int a[] = {2,1,2,3,4};

int b[] = {0};

for(int i = 0; i < a.size; i++)
{

    if(a[i] == a[i+1])
    {
         //duplicate found
         //copy it to second array
        b[i] = a[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: This wrong! you need to do again another for loop if you want to do it that way, and that's o(N^2)