# Finding duplicate elements in an array without using nested loops

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I recently had an interview which consisted of following problem. Please help with possible solutions.

Write a method in Java to find duplicate elements in an integer array without using nested loops ( for/ while / do while, etc ) and without using library functions or standard API's.

Comment: What was your attempt? (Hint use recu.....)

Comment: can you use collection framework?arraylist?

Comment: @DevChoudhary Did the interviewer say you can't use loops at all or just that you can't nest loops?

Comment: Very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944458/find-duplicate-element-in-array-in-time-on

Comment: loops can be used, but not nested ones

Comment: How is this a duplicate of the question indicated above? This question asks for all duplicate elements, the question tagged as duplicate asks only for an element. Very clear distinction between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Hey the below solution has complexity O(n) and works fine. Check if it helps.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = new int[]{10,3,5,10,5,4,6};
        String distinctElement="";
        String repetitiveTerms="";
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            if(i==0){
                distinctElement+=a[i]+" ";
            }
            else if(distinctElement.contains(""+a[i])){
                repetitiveTerms+=a[i]+" ";
            }
            else{
                distinctElement+=a[i]+" ";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What part of *without using nested loops ( for/ while / do while, etc )* said that you could use loops?

Comment: It's not much of a challenge if you can use loops. My understanding of the question is that you can't use loops. Let's wait for the OP to clarify.

Comment: i think loops are allowed but not nested

Comment: Ok that's fine but "NESTED" is clear to us right. So you should not downgrade the answers unless you are sure about it

Comment: @Fast Snail : No it won't be problem. If you will see the code carefully i have inserted spaces between the elements so 1 0 cannot be 10. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: @KulbhushanSingh oops i didn't see that.good

Comment: @Fast Snail : That's ok :)

Comment: I think this will fail if the array has negative values, eg: `"0 -1 5".contains("1") == true`  or values with different scale eg: `"100 20".contains("10") == true`

Comment: Yeah that will fail. What could be the probable solution @Titus

Comment: I think `distinctElement.contains(" "+ a[i] + " ")` will partially fix that (it won't check the last added element because the `distinctElement` doesn't terminate with a space, eg: `"10 20 30".contains(" 30 ") == false`).

Comment: I very much doubt that this has O(n) complexity, as `contains` is just another loop. Also i'd argue it doesn't fulfill the not library functions part.

Comment: loops can be used , but not nested ones

Comment: @Dev See if you the above logic helps...