# Finding first duplicate in an array and returning the minimal index

Tags: javascript, algorithm

So the question reads:

> Given an array a that contains only numbers in the range from 1 to a.length, find the first duplicate number for which the second occurrence has the minimal index. In other words, if there are more than 1 duplicated numbers, return the number for which the second occurrence has a smaller index than the second occurrence of the other number does. If there are no such elements, return -1.
>   Write a solution with O(n) time complexity and O(1) additional space complexity.

I have a solution, but apparently it's not fast enough and stalls when there are over a thousand items in the array.

This is what I have:

```
function firstDuplicate(arr) {
  let dictionary = {};

  for(let i = 0, ii = arr.length; i < ii; i++) {
    for(let z = i+1, zz = arr.length; z < zz; z++) {
      if(arr[i] === arr[z]) {
        if(dictionary.hasOwnProperty(arr[i])) {
          if(dictionary[arr[i]] !== 0 && dictionary[arr[i]] > z) {
            dictionary[i] = z;
          }
        } else {
          dictionary[arr[i]] = z;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  let answer = [];

  for(key in dictionary) {
    // [array number, position];
    answer.push([key, dictionary[key]]);
  };

if(answer.length > 0) {
  return Number(answer.sort((a, b) => {
    return a[1]-b[1];
  })[0][0]);
}

return -1;
}
```

I think converting the object into an array and then sorting the array after the answers are complete slows down the whole function. Using built in JS methods like `forEach`, `map` and `sort` (like I did above), slows the code/function down even more. There is obviously a better and more accurate way to do this, so I'm asking for some JS masterminds to help me out on this.

Comment: try looking at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944458/find-duplicate-element-in-array-in-time-on?rq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can keep adding numbers to a dictionary as keys with values as their index, and as soon as you find a repeating key in the dictionary return its value. This will be O(n) time complexity and O(n) space complexity.

```js
function firstDuplicate(arr) {
  var dictionary = {};

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
if(dictionary[arr[i]] !== undefined)
     return arr[i];
else
   dictionary[arr[i]] = i;
  }

  return -1;
}

console.log(firstDuplicate([2, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2]));
```

Since the numbers are between 1 to arr.length you can iterate on the array. For each arr[i] use arr[i] as index and make the element present and arr[arr[i]] negative, then the first arr[arr[i]] negative return arr[i]. This give O(1) space complexity  and O(n) time complexity you can do this:

```js
function firstDuplicate(arr) {

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
if(arr[Math.abs(arr[i])] < 0)
     return Math.abs(arr[i]);
else
   arr[Math.abs(arr[i])] = 0 - arr[Math.abs(arr[i])];
  }

  return -1;
}

console.log(firstDuplicate([2, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2]));
```

Comment: this one fails when the array is `[2, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2]`. Expected output `3`, get output `1`.

Comment: @MabehAl-ZuqYadeek I was returning index, its correct now.

Comment: Other answers were good as well. Thanks for your help. Can you explain your thought process or good resources to think the way you have? I completely went off the deep and wrote unnecessary code.

Comment: @MabehAl-ZuqYadeek I have updated my answer with explanations

Comment: @MabehAl-ZuqYadeek you were almost the right track with using dictionary, with dictionary you can always find a key value pair and if you find a key in the dictionary means you have already seen that number before which means it is being repeated.

Comment: @Jassi "array a that contains only numbers in the range from 1 to a.length" as it says in the question, that means [2,2] is invalid input according to the question.

Comment: @Dij that is true. Actually this question was part of Code Fight and there it was numbers <=a.length. I posted the answer below which will work if a.length is max

Answer (score 1):

```js
function firstDuplicate(arr) {
   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var num = Math.abs(arr[i]);
        if(arr[num] < 0)
            return num;
        arr[num] = - arr[num];
    }
    return -1;
} 
console.log(firstDuplicate([2,2,3,1,2]));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function firstDuplicate(arr) {
    var numMap = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (numMap[arr[i]]) {
            return arr[i];
        }
        numMap[arr[i]] = true;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer mentioned by @dij is great, but will fail for [2,2] or [2,3,3],
a little change 
for input [2,2], i=0 we get a[ Math.abs[a[0] ] = a[2] = undefined
so we remove 1 from a[ Math.abs[a[0] -1 ] this will work now

```
function firstDuplicate(arr) {

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[Math.abs(arr[i])-1] < 0)
      return Math.abs(arr[i]);
    else
      arr[Math.abs(arr[i])-1] = 0 - arr[Math.abs(arr[i])-1];
   }

   return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below:

```
function getCountOccurence(A) {

    let result = [];
    A.forEach(elem => {
        if (result.length > 0) {
            let isOccure = false;
            result.some((element) => {
                if (element.element == elem) {
                    element.count++;
                    isOccure = true;
                }
            });
            if (!isOccure) {
                result.push({element: elem, count: 1});
            }
        } else {
            result.push({element: elem, count: 1});
        }
    });
    return result;
}

function getFirstRepeatingElement(A) {

    let array = getCountOccurence(A);
    array.some((element)=> {
        if (element.count > 1) {
            result = element.element;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Could you make some explanation to the code you posted?