# Convert a String to array of bits

Tags: java, arrays, java-8

I would like to convert a String consisting of 0's and 1's to an array of bits.
The String is of length ~30000 and is sparse (mostly 0s, few 1s)
For example, given a string
"00000000100000000010000100000000001000"
I would like to convert it to an array of bits which will store
[00000000100000000010000100000000001000]

I am thinking of using [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) or [OpenBitSet](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/util/OpenBitSet.html)
Is there a better way? The use case is to perform logical OR efficiently.

I am thinking along these lines

```
final OpenBitSet logicalOrResult = new OpenBitSet(); 
for (final String line : lines) {

   final OpenBitSet myBitArray = new OpenBitSet(); 
   int pos = 0;
   for (final char c : str.toCharArray()) {
         myBitArray.set(pos) = c;
         pos++;
   }
   logicalOrResult.or(myBitArray);
}
```

Comment: @StevenA.Lowe It is not.

Comment: @StevenA.Lowe It's either a good question or a bad one. Why do you care if it's homework?

Comment: @AnubianNoob: if it's homework, and I tell the OP the answer, then they've learned nothing. see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework for semi-official policy

Comment: @Tad: tell us what you've tried instead of asking for a "better" answer; otherwise this is likely to get closed rapidly as a homework or unclear question

Comment: @StevenA.Lowe But a post "looks like homework..." is really not constructive.

Comment: @AnubianNoob: i thought it was more constructive than just voting to close the question ;)

Comment: @StevenA.Lowe added what I was thinking so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `BitSet` ranging over values between `0` and `30000` requires a `long` array of size less than 500, so you can assume that `BitSet.or` (or the respective `OpenBitSet` method) will be sufficiently fast, despite the sparsity. It looks like `OpenBitSet` has better performance than `BitSet`, but apart from this it doesn't really matter which you use, both will implement `or` efficiently. However, *be sure* to pass the length of the String to the `(Open)BitSet` constructor to avoid reallocations of the internal `long` array during construction!

If your strings are much longer and your sparsity is extreme, you could also consider storing them as a sorted list of `Integer`s (or `int`s, if you use a library like Trove), representing the indices which contain a `1`. A bitwise `or` can be implemented in a merge(sort)-like fashion, which is quite efficient (time O(n + m), where n, m are the numbers of ones in each string). I suspect that in your scenario it will be slower than the `BitSet` approach though.

Comment: my BitSet will range over values 1 and 0 - not 0 and 30000. Is this what you mean?

Comment: No. Your `BitSet` *represents* a set of integers between 0 and some upper limit. E.g., the bitset 01001101 represents the set {0, 2, 3, 6} - the set of indices set to 1. This is also what constitutes the `toString()` representation of a `BitSet`. Since your strings are of length ~30000, the corresponding set of 1-indices ranges over values between 0 and 30000.

Answer (score 2):

[`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) can parse it and store it, and do bitwise operations:

```
BigInteger x = new BigInteger(bitString, 2);
BigInteger y = new BigInteger(otherBitString, 2);
x = x.or(y);
System.out.println(x.toString(2));
```

Comment: do you know whether there are any benchmarks between BigInteger and OpenBitSet and BitSet (or any other library) for performing logical OR?

Comment: @Tad I do not know, but you can easily compare them by doing the benchmarks within the intended application.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through each character:

```
boolean[] bits = new boolean[str.length];

for (int i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i).equals("1")
        bits[i] = true;
    else if (str.charAt(i).equals("0")
        bits[i] = false;
}
```

If you want to be memory efficient, you could try [RLE (Run Length Encoding)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).

Comment: I like this approach but I have read in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383551/what-is-the-size-of-a-boolean-variable-in-java that using BitSet has a better optimization than an array of booleans. I was also considering RLE, which would be great since my array is sparse, but I am not sure how to do logical OR on compressed array - I guess I would need to decompress it first, unless I am missing something.