# Out Of Memory Error: Java heap space - Using big array size

Tags: java, arrays, out-of-memory

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Using a 2D array of [100000][100000] and other two arrays of [100000] each. I need these three arrays in the whole program so can't free their memory.

Already tried VM Options -Xmx512m in Netbeans

Please be specific and Step by Step, I am newbie in Java and Netbeans.

Thanks in advance for you help....

Comment: What the type of the array, try run with -Xmx1200m (max of window xp) or more almost up to your maximum free memory

Comment: That 2D array is going to take 10GB if the elements are bytes, 40GB if they're ints... So you're going to need at least `element_size_in_bytes * 10` GB of RAM...

Comment: You just need to apply what you learnt in arithmetics: 100000 * 100000 = 10 billion. Asuming these are arrays of bytes, that means you need 10 billion bytes, i.e. 10 GB of memory. Your 512MB won't cut it.

Comment: or 1.2GB for boolean

Comment: @RoyShmuli That's not guaranteed, booleans can be bigger than 1 bit.

Comment: @zenith in java primitive boolean take 1 bit, the object that contain it (array) take 12 bytes(depent 32/64 bit) + 100K/8 and the result rounded to full bytes.. for example size of array[7] equal to size of array[1] (booleans)

Comment: @RoyShmuli, although VM dependent, Java's boolean take a about a bute of memory in practice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383551/what-is-the-size-of-a-boolean-variable-in-java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's do some math. You're allocating a 10,000,000,000 element two dimensional array, plus another two arrays of 100,000 elements.

That's 10,002,000,000 elements. If each of them is an int, that's 40,008,000,000 bytes. That's 37.26 **Giga** bytes.

Your `-Xmx512m` isn't nearly enough, you need something closer to `-Xmx60G` if these are really ints or `-Xmx15G` in the best case scenario, in which the elements are bytes (e.g. booleans). But that will probably won't work since you (probably) don't have enough physical memory. To me it sounds like you need some disk backed storage, or a database.

Either re-think what you're doing and how you're doing it, or use a machine with that much physical memory.

Comment: Thanks Bart... Got your point... Didn't thought in that way... how to work around this? I am working on graphs with around 80K vertices and then finding a shortest path between two given vertices.

Comment: @ManojPathak If you can't fit the entire graph in memory, store it on the disk, and read only relevant pieces of data each time. Something like Neo4j (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo4j) might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions they are really helpful :-)

Comment: You have probably chosen wrong algorithm. There is a lot of algorithms, that doesn't require NxN matrix. Consider Dijkstra's algorithm if you have a graph with positive costs or Bellman-Ford's algorithm if you don't or A* if you have a good heuristic. Those algorithms are fast and don't require much space. I've been working at graphs with 100 000's of vertices and millions of edges on high-end desktop computer and it worked well.