# Floating and Double types range in java

Tags: java

I am beginner in Java and I am just reading one of the pdfs for beginners like me. So in my book I found this:

[image]

So for example the floating point numbers may be within the range of

> 1.4E-45 to 3.4028235E+38

So according to my math, that number can be very small (near the zero) or quite large, but it CAN NOT be a negative number.

Am I correct?

Comment: That PDF is wrong for `float`, `double` and `boolean`. [What is the size of a boolean variable in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383551/what-is-the-size-of-a-boolean-variable-in-java). Also `float` and `double` are both floating point and can both be negative.

Comment: Mhmm this is a reference to it: http://www.ebooksbucket.com/uploads/itprogramming/java/Java_in_a_Nutshell_6th_Edition.pdf

Comment: Being pedantic, the default value for `long` is `0L` and the default for `float` is `0.0f`, and `boolean` uses 1 byte and a field or in an array of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book states the `MIN_VALUE` and `MAX_VALUE` for the floating point types.  This range describes available precision but it is certainly *not* the case that all values must fall between `MIN_VALUE` and `MAX_VALUE` as you can easily confirm by assigning zero or a negative number to a `float` variable.

Floating point values (`float` and `double`) can be one of the following:

- `NaN` (not a number)
- negative infinity
- a negative number between `-MAX_VALUE` and `-MIN_VALUE`
- negative zero
- positive zero
- a positive number between `MIN_VALUE` and `MAX_VALUE`
- positive infinity

Answer (score 2):

Float range is approximately **±3.40282347E+38F**
(6-7 significant decimal digits)
Java implements IEEE 754 standard.

Refer below links

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

http://cs-fundamentals.com/java-programming/java-primitive-data-types.php

Comment: Being pedantic, Java utilises the IEEE-754 operations implemented in the CPU. +1

Answer (score 1):

here you are considering the minimimum value of float .
minimum value of float `(MIN_VALUE)` prints the `most accurate float` it can get, but not the mathematical minimum it can represent.

`integers` can hold negative values and `integers` can be `cast` to `float` later.
think about that.

range of float : `32 bits   -3.4E+38 to +3.4E+38`