# What is Scala's cheapest type?

Tags: scala, types

I need to use a type (any type) as a marker in an implicit as a type parameter, to distinguish it from another implicit. It's weird, but this may be another question.

Since I can use any type, I was thinking of using the cheapest one, in terms of **memory footprint** and **initialization time**. It may not affect performance too much in this case, but the question is interesting: Which one is Scala's cheapest type?

In Java, the answer is obviously `java.lang.Object`. But Scala has a few "interesting" types: `Any`, `AnyVal` types, and bottom types with possible optimizations around them. The `Nothing` type cannot be instantiated, so it is excluded from this comparison.

Comment: Interesting, I would have said that the cheapest type in java was a simple int.

Comment: I'm not sure how "cheap" this is, but Nothing might be usable: `def x(_ : Nothing) = (); x(null.asInstanceOf[Nothing])` Just *don't* try to use that Nothing :-)

Comment: It would also be interesting to see a question on the "root" issue.

Comment: @Adrian Fritsch: how many marker values do you need? just two (marked/not marked)?

Comment: This smells like premature optimization.

Comment: Is this type parameterized? That matters a big deal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you choose `Any` or `AnyVal`, then any primitive you pass will be boxed, so that's probably out.

`AnyRef` is a good choice indeed.

If there isn't any type parameterization going on, then the "primitives" are also good choices -- `Boolean` or `Int`, for instance.

And there's also `Null`, which is a very interesting choice because it doesn't allocate anything at all, and it is a literal, so it is bound to be fast. Without knowing what exactly are you doing with it, I can't tell whether that's valid choice.

Another interesting option is `java.lang.Integer` (using the static method `valueOf`), because it guarantees reference equality for small values (you'd have to check the docs to see what's the precise range), meaning there's no allocation involved.

Comment: `java.lang.Integer` doesn't guarantee reference equality for small values. The expression `new Integer(5)` always creates a new separate instance. You may be thinking of autoboxing. `Integer i = 5` will always assign the same object to `i`.

Answer (score 13):

It depends on your exact problem, but the cheapest construct in Scala - or in any language - has got to be one that doesn't exist at all... (at least, not at runtime)

Allow me to introduce [Phantom Types](http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2010/10/phantom-types-in-haskell-and-scala.html), allowing the compiler to statically do the Right Thing, but erased to nothingness before they hit the JVM.

In a similar vein, you can easily distinguish two differently typed objects without needing any marker fields.  This is a good candidate for `case object`s, and works really nicely alongside pattern matching.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I get what you mean with "cheapest type"... In Java cheapest numerical type in terms of memory *can* be byte, but from performance POV Java is optimized to work with int. In fact many (or most) languages are optimized to work with int (even DB engines). Scala is JVM language, so I would say that better to use int.

**UPDATE:** if the question is about "marked / not marked" suitable data type, I would use boolean primitive.

> if you type boolean in a Scala
>   program, the type you'll actually get
>   is scala.Boolean. Or if you type
>   float, you'll get scala.Float. When
>   you compile your Scala code to Java
>   bytecodes, however, Scala will compile
>   these types to Java's primitive types
>   where possible to get the performance
>   benefits of Java's primitive types.

Nothing is an Any, which is kind of Object in Java, and any Object needs more memory than any primitive type

And btw, using boolean as marker is natural, it improves your code readability (and hence support, understanding by others). Even if there is anything else, more optimized I would not do premature optimization and would choose boolean.

Comment: byte doesn't take "one" byte in memory but it must be aligned, so 4/8. The exception is byte[]

Comment: @bestsss: agreed, I was wrong talking about 1byte size (this is according to javadoc which tells about 8bit); on the other hand how much does it actually take depends on JVM implementation (as I know there is overhead, also reference to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229886/size-of-a-byte-in-memory-java). Some JVMs can "treat" byte type as 32bit number... I changed my answer according to your remark. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since Scala runs on top of Java I would assume that the same answer would work also in the Scala world. a Scala object of type Any is just a Java Object of some sort.

In Java I think a primitive type like int, short or byte would be cheaper than Object, but those types might be wrapped/boxed in Scala. (not 100% sure about that though.)

**Update**

If for some reason it has to be a object and not a primitive type, String might be the best, since strings are interned in the VM. So there will usually only be one instance of the object throughout the application.

Comment: "The Scala compiler uses Java arrays, primitive types, and native arithmetic where possible in the compiled code" (from "Programming in Scala" book) - seems like they are not wrapped (at least during runtime).

Comment: not analysis the code to avoid wrapping will be just lazy, lazy coding; `intern` of strings is leak prone and it doesn't improve performance

Answer (score 0):

Scala wraps primitive types, when you run method calls of the wrapper, which the primitive type does not implement. So ie. 1024*512 is not wrapped but in 1024.toInt*512 the 1024 is getting wrapped.