# Size of a 'long' in memory - Java

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory, visualvm

### Reviewed

1. [size-of-a-byte-in-memory-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229886/size-of-a-byte-in-memory-java)
2. [byte-in-java-takes-4-bytes-by-default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312880/byte-in-java-takes-4-bytes-by-default)

I am still trying to figure out why **`long`** and **`double`** in Java consuming **`12 bytes`** instead of **`8 bytes`** in memory

**Sure there is wrong assumptions somewhere; please guide me..**

I have analyzed it using two ways,

1. [Java VisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/) [image]
2. [Java Instrumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html) based [memory-measurer](https://github.com/DimitrisAndreou/memory-measurer)

Following is my logic/assumption/source info,

1. Define a single float or long property in a class and check its memory footprint
2. Object will carry its own Meta Data worth `12 bytes =  [CLASS INFO OF 4 BYTES] + [FLAGS INFO OF 4 BYTES] + [LOCK INFO OF 4 BYTES]`
3. Class size will be `Total Memory - Meta Data`
4. Result received is `12 bytes => 24 bytes (Total Memory) - 12 bytes (Meta Data)`
5. JDK: 1.8.0_65; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
6. OS: Windows 8.1
7. [Test program](https://github.com/inbravo/java-src/blob/master/src/com/inbravo/memory/PrimitiveVarsSizeTest.java)

[**ANSWER**] Difference of 4 bytes is owing to Padding Applied by JVM. Thanks Andy Turner...

Comment: @AndyTurner but inside the `DoubleClass` and `LongClass` there are primitive `long` and `double` variables.

Comment: @radoh `DoubleClass` and `LongClass` has its own meta data worth 12 bytes + 8 byte primitive `long` or `double` + 4 byte padding => 24 bytes total. I was not able to know that from where 4 bytes were coming in picture. Memory padding was the correct answer by Andy .... :)

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/258150/3788176):

> In a modern 64-bit JDK, an object has a 12-byte header, padded to a multiple of 8 bytes

The extra 4 bytes is padding to get to a multiple of 8.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the size of double:

```
double numDouble=2;
long size=(long)(numDouble*Double.SIZE) / Byte.SIZE;
System.out.println(size);
```

output: 16