# Java: get length of string when repressented as bytes of some encoding

Tags: java

What is the best / cleanest way of determining size of Java String after conversion into byte array, preferably without first converting it into the array?

-EDIT
By size I mean length of byte array that would be result of getBytes method

Comment: Do you know the encoding?

Comment: Wait, do you want the size of the `String` or the size of the `byte[]`?

Comment: "Size" needs some more detail.  Do you mean predicting the array size of the byte array?

Comment: @christopher I'm given few different encodings(Charset instaces)

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Size of The byte[]

Comment: You would have to redo the work the charset is going to do in converting. In some cases it would be straightforward, but there's always the chance your implementation would have bugs. I'm not sure if this is a good idea.

Comment: There is "AverageBytesPerChar", which may be of some use:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html#averageBytesPerChar()

Comment: Did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229886/size-of-a-byte-in-memory-java

Comment: Oh, and MaxBytesPerChar, which is what you'll have to support anyway

Comment: @user2348184 I'm aware of Java memory alignment, heap memory-saving is not the case here

Comment: There is a relatively simple algorithm which you can use to examine each byte of a UTF8 string in turn in turn and determine which are 1, 2, and 4-byte codes.  I coded it several times when working on the IBM iSeries JVM.  I just don't remember what it is.

Comment: @HotLicks Was it something like [this](http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2008-06-05-faster-utf8-strlen.html)?

Comment: Something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are encodings where you can know the length in bytes - all those which use fixed byte length per character. Examples are US-ASCII, ISO-8859-1 and UTF-16.

When using variable byte length, like the popular UTF-8 you cannot know a priory the length of the byte array.

Comment: But it isn't so easy to know how many characters are in a string (as opposed to how many chars are in a string, which is trivial). Consider high and low surrogates, as in a string which contains, say, Egyptian hieroglyphics. Also, "a priori".

Comment: I think you can from the String.length() javadoc: "Returns the length of this string. The length is equal to the number of Unicode code units in the string." and "Returns: the length of the sequence of characters represented by this object."

Comment: That's really only true for the BMP, the Basic Multilingual Plane of Unicode. Java `Strings` are stored in UTF-16BE format, so the character U+13000 is stored as the surrogate pair U+D80C, U+DC00, and `String.length()` just returns the length of the underlying `char[]`.

Comment: `new StringBuilder().appendCodePoint(0x13000).toString().length()`

Comment: It's really unfortunate, there are also bugs with `equalsIgnoreCase`, although there aren't many scripts outside the BMP that actually have cased letters. (The Deseret script is the only one I know of.)

Comment: However, I think that for most languages, String.length() returns the correct answer in characters. Hieroglyphics, while being an interesting case, is a really edge case I think 99% of the software in the world won't encounter (and the same for most Unicode characters above 2^16)

Comment: Yes, it will work for much more than 99% of cases. But it will break for *all* Unicode characters over 2^16. I just picked hieroglyphs because they're outside the BMP. It's being over 64k that breaks it. Actually converting to a byte[] and checking the length works 100% of the time.