# byte & short in Java. How to use it correctly?

Tags: java

As I know, there is good practice use `int` variables for arithmetical operations. Because, if we use "byte" or `short` JVM regardless cast it to `int` in arithmetical operations.

So, I want to ask, where programmers employ `byte` and `short` in Java.

P.S. Schildt in his book say that byte can be "useful when you're working with a stream of data from a network or file". But I can't find any example's.

Comment: A key difference is the actual size in memory. A byte is 1 byte. A short is already two bytes and an int is 4 bytes. Depending on what size of data you want to save, you use the most suitable type. Especially in an embedded environment, where memory is limited. Please see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html for further information.

Comment: You could use it for constants. For example: 
`public static final byte BLOCKS_AMOUNT = 3;`

Comment: I would look in the java.io or java.nio packages or any code which uses them. You should be able to find millions of examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna change some data in binary file , maybe you need byte.
As a high-level language , memory useage is not a problem , best practice is
if you don't know what you should to use , just int , like tcp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use them to save memory, since `int` is `32-bit signed`, byte is `8-bit signed` and short is `16-bit signed`. In cases where you have a large amount of these items, and you know the maximum value will fit in the data type you chose you're saving memory.

For example `int test = 1;` will still take up 32 bits of memory while it's contents would also fit in a `byte`

Comment: Overheads depends on platform, but the primitive size is constant, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229886/size-of-a-byte-in-memory-java